# Rename master branch for both local and remote Git repositories

Tags: git, git-branch, git-pull

I have the branch `master` which tracks the remote branch `origin/master`.

I want to rename them to `master-old` both locally and on the remote. Is this possible?

For other users who tracked `origin/master` (and who always updated their local `master` branch via `git pull`), what would happen after I renamed the remote branch?
Would their `git pull` still work or would it throw an error that it couldn't find `origin/master` anymore?

Then, further on, I want to create a new `master` branch (both locally and remote). Again, after I did this, what would happen now if the other users do `git pull`?

I guess all this would result in a lot of trouble. Is there a clean way to get what I want? Or should I just leave `master` as it is and create a new branch `master-new` and just work there further on?

Comment: The recipe given in the accepted answer does apply to a branch of any name, but the caveats (as noted) do not, due to the (by default) special role of the _master_ branch in Git.

Comment: @kynan: I think I don't understand. What caveats do apply to master and don't apply on other branches? If it would be a branch named xy and other people have tracked that branch, how would that be different?

Comment: The caveat that you can't normally delete the remote master. That does not apply to Aristotle's answer though, so you might want to mark that as the accepted answer. You're correct, any `git push -f` affects the ability to `pull` from any remote tracking branch.

Comment: you can create a new branch `master-old` that points to the same commit as the previous `master` branch. Then you can overwrite the `master` branch with your new changes by doing a `merge` with the `ours` strategy. Doing a merge works when the remote does not allow non-fastforward changes. That also means other users won't have forced updates.

Comment: @kynan `master` is only special as long as it's the only existing branch. As soon as you have more than one, all branches are on an equal footing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I rename a local Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591213/how-do-i-rename-a-local-git-branch)

Comment: Remote only solution without local manipulations is available in comments in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753888/renaming-branches-remotely-in-git

Answer (score 651, accepted):

The closest thing to renaming is deleting and then recreating on the remote. For example:

```bash
git branch -m master master-old
git push remote :master         # Delete master
git push remote master-old      # Create master-old on remote

git checkout -b master some-ref # Create a new local master
git push remote master          # Create master on remote
```

However, this has a lot of caveats. First, no existing checkouts will know about the rename - Git does *not* attempt to track branch renames. If the new `master` doesn't exist yet, *git pull* will error out. If the new `master` has been created. the pull will attempt to merge `master` and `master-old`. So it's generally a bad idea unless you have the cooperation of everyone who has checked out the repository previously.

Note: Newer versions of Git will not allow you to delete the master branch remotely by default. You can override this by setting the `receive.denyDeleteCurrent` configuration value to `warn` or `ignore` on the *remote* repository. Otherwise, if you're ready to create a new master right away, skip the `git push remote :master` step, and pass `--force` to the `git push remote master` step. Note that if you're not able to change the remote's configuration, you won't be able to completely delete the master branch!

This caveat only applies to the current branch (usually the `master` branch); any other branch can be deleted and recreated as above.

Comment: branches are just a (name, hash) pair - nothing more, nothing less. There is the reflog on branches, but this is never exposed to remote clients.

Comment: I would create master-old on remote before deleting master on remote. I'm just paranoid.

Comment: No dice at second command: "remote: error: By default, deleting the current branch is denied, because the next
remote: error: 'git clone' won't result in any file checked out, causing confusion.
remote: error: 
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyDeleteCurrent' configuration variable t
remote: error: 'warn' or 'ignore' in the remote repository to allow deleting th
remote: error: current branch, with or without a warning message.
remote: error: 
remote: error: To squelch this message, you can set it to 'refuse'.
remote: error: refusing to delete the current branch: refs/heads/master"

Comment: @kdt, the answer you seek is in the message you just pasted... But yeah, newer versions of git are unhappy about deleting the master branch. I'll update the example.

Comment: @AdamDymitruk no need to be paranoid unless you believe that the server receiving the push deleting the branch ref does something extra (which may be the case for GitHub). Git by default won't clean up unless you tell it to.

Comment: Aristotle's answer below allows you to do this without deleting the master, so I'd think that preferable.

Comment: it would be clear and SAFE if you can use `new-branch-name` and `old-branch-name` instead of `master`/`master-old`, thus this is a general problem.

Comment: If the deleted branch (here: master) is not referenced by other branches, git might garbage collect all commits on that ... well ... “branch”. – Some git porcelain commands trigger a garbage collection. – Therefore: create the new name first (pointing to the same commit), then delete the old name.

Comment: `git push remote :master`

> fatal: 'remote' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: @vee, I had the same error - try `git push origin`.

Comment: @vee git has excellent auto-completion, just type `git push [TABULATOR]`

Comment: with this recipe I am getting `! [remote rejected] master (refusing to delete the current branch: refs/heads/master)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/me/repo'` on `git push -f remote :master `

Comment: Step 2 fails: 'remote' does not appear to be a git repository

Comment: @JesseBarnum You should replace 'remote' with the name of your remote repository. Conventionally is called origin. You can list your actual remotes using "git remote"

Answer (score 272):

Assuming you are currently on `master`:

```
git push origin master:master-old        # 1
git branch master-old origin/master-old  # 2
git reset --hard $new_master_commit      # 3
git push -f origin                       # 4
```

1. First make a `master-old` branch in the `origin` repository, based off of the `master` commit in the local repository.
2. Create a new local branch for this new `origin/master-old` branch (which will automatically be set up properly as a tracking branch).
3. Now point your local `master` to whichever commit you want it to point to.
4. Finally, force-change `master` in the `origin` repository to reflect your new local `master`.

(If you do it in any other way, you need at least one more step to ensure that `master-old` is properly set up to track `origin/master-old`. None of the other solutions posted at the time of this writing include that.)

Comment: This is better answer than "the answer", I agree, but for people who came here to just rename a branch (not explicitly master), the 3rd step doesn't make much sense.

Comment: It makes absolutely no difference to the answer whether you are on `master` or another branch. The question was badly titled though, it asks about a task more complex than *just* renaming a branch.

Comment: This turned out to be the solution that worked for me.  I was trying to replace master with another branch.  I did a git log -1 origin/what_i_want_as_new_master to get the $new_master_commit for step 3.
After the push (step 4), other devs would pull and get messages "your branch is ahead of master by 295 commits." To fix this I sent out an email letting them know to each run: git pull; git checkout some_random_branch; git branch -D master; git pull; git checkout master;  Basically, they need to remove their local master and pull the new version otherwise they're at the wrong place locally.

Comment: You could have done that far more easily: assuming they’re already on `master` then they could just do `git fetch && git reset --hard origin/master` to force their local `master` to be the same as the one on `origin`. I have documented this, as well as the more complex case where you have local commits on top of `master` that you want to keep, in http://stackoverflow.com/q/4084868

Comment: Make sure that the remote config file has "denyNonFastforwards = false" or you will get "remote: error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/master (you should pull first)"

Answer (score 184):

With Git v1.7, I think this has changed slightly. Updating your local branch's tracking reference to the new remote is now very easy.

```
git branch -m old_branch new_branch         # Rename branch locally    
git push origin :old_branch                 # Delete the old branch    
git push --set-upstream origin new_branch   # Push the new branch, set local branch to track the new remote
```

Comment: An alternative to ```--set-upstream``` is as follows: Once you have your branch renamed locally and deleted on the origin, simply do:

```git push -u --all```

Comment: What happens to the rest of the team after this is done? What should other team members do to switch to the new branch?

Comment: This will not work with master branch, since git will not allow you to delete the remote master.

Comment: @AlexandreNeto In this case you can execute the 3rd line before the 2nd, set the default branch to `new_branch` and then eventually delete the remote `master` with the 2nd line.

Comment: Amazingly simple steps. This is the best answer of the question

Comment: This is the most simple and working solution to rename a non master branch. Tested on git 2.4 and it works!!

Comment: This also will work on master branch if your are using github. You just need to push new branch first and then in repository settings set is as default. Then you can delete master branch.

Comment: Will all the History of the old_branch be there in the new_branch (In case of doing this with master for the sake of clarity)

Comment: To delete the remote branch `git push origin --delete old_branch` is slightly more readable.

Comment: Yes, definitely best answer here. Always worth checking GitHub as well since they usually have the answer too: https://gist.github.com/lttlrck/9628955

Comment: best answer out there!

Answer (score 42):

There are many ways to rename the branch, but I am going to focus on the bigger problem: **"how to allow clients to fast-forward and not have to mess with their branches locally"**.

First a quick picture:
[image: renaming master branch and allowing clients to fast-forward]

This is something actually easy to do; but don't abuse it.
The whole idea hinges on merge commits; as they allow fast-forward, and link histories of a branch with another.

### renaming the branch:

```
# rename the branch "master" to "master-old"
# this works even if you are on branch "master"
git branch -m master master-old
```

### creating the new "master" branch:

```
# create master from new starting point
git branch master <new-master-start-point>
```

### creating a merge commit to have a parent-child history:

```
# now we've got to fix the new branch...
git checkout master

# ... by doing a merge commit that obsoletes
# "master-old" hence the "ours" strategy.
git merge -s ours master-old
```

### and voila.

```
git push origin master
```

This works because creating a `merge` commit allows **fast-forwarding** the branch to a new revision.

### using a sensible merge commit message:

```
renamed branch "master" to "master-old" and use commit ba2f9cc as new "master"
-- this is done by doing a merge commit with "ours" strategy which obsoletes
   the branch.

these are the steps I did:

git branch -m master master-old
git branch master ba2f9cc
git checkout master
git merge -s ours master-old
```

Comment: Thanks! `git merge -s ours master-old` is the crucial piece that the other answers miss. Also, "easy to do" does not mean "easy to understand, or find out" which seems to be the case with much of git, but I digress.

Comment: I love the fact that no deletions are mentioned and that the transition for those working with clones of upstream is "seamless". Thank you!

Comment: Does this work if master has changes you don't want master-new?

Comment: @EthanFischer Yes. The merge uses the "ours" strategy, which basically creates an empty merge. But that empty merge is enough to trick git into believing that it's a fast-forward push.

Answer (score 38):

```
git checkout -b new-branch-name
git push remote-name new-branch-name :old-branch-name
```

You may have to manually switch to `new-branch-name` before deleting `old-branch-name`

Comment: Does any part of this solution delete the local old-branch-name, or is that a serparate exercise?

Comment: I thinks at the end must be run `git branch -d old-branch-name` for delete local old branch.

Comment: You can push changes by only one command: `git push remote-name new-branch-name :old-branch-name`.

Comment: This way will no you complicate the git history? Because you are opening a new branch instead just renaming the current one.

Comment: @androider No. Branches in git is [a simple references](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-References).

Comment: git push origin EPIC_localname:EPIC_remotename :oldname

Comment: In my experience this doesn't update the tracking branch of the local branch correctly.

Answer (score 12):

I'm assuming you're still asking about the same situation as in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526670/git-better-way-for-git-revert-without-additional-reverted-commit). That is, master-new will not contain master-old in its history.* If you call master-new "master", you will effectively have rewritten history. It does not matter *how* you get into a state in which master is not a descendant of a previous position of master, simply that it is in that state.

Other users attempting to pull while master does not exist will simply have their pulls fail (no such ref on remote), and once it exists again in a new place, their pulls will have to attempt to merge their master with the new remote master, just as if you merged master-old and master-new in your repository. Given what you're trying to do here, the merge would have conflicts. (If they were resolved, and the result was pushed back into the repository, you'd be in an even worse state - both versions of history there.)

To answer your question simply: you should accept that sometimes there will be mistakes in your history. This is okay. It happens to everyone. There are reverted commits in the git.git repository. The important thing is that once we publish history, it is something everyone can trust.

*If it did, this would be equivalent to pushing some changes onto master, and then creating a new branch where it used to be. No problem.

Comment: Yea, it's the same problem, just was one idea how to solve it. But even if I would not do this branch-renaming, I was interesting if it would be possible.

I thought such refs as "master" are only references to specific commits. I really don't want to change any history. I thought I would just point the master-reference to another head.

This also means, I can never ever use a branch name again if I have ever used it before?

Comment: Indeed, branches are refs - pointers to commits. The thing is, we expect the head of a branch to evolve in a particular way (namely, always fast-forwarding). From the point of view of someone else, moving a branch in your public repo is the same as rewriting the history of the branch. It no longer points to a commit containing everything it used to.

Answer (score 10):

The [selected answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1527004/155640) failed when I tried it. It throws an error: `refusing to delete the current branch: refs/heads/master`. I guess I'll post what works for me:

```
git checkout master             # If not in master already

git branch placeholder          # Create placeholder branch
git checkout placeholder        # Check out to placeholder
git push remote placeholder     # Push placeholder to remote repository

git branch -d master            # Remove master in local repository
git push remote :master         # Remove master from remote repository.
```

The trick is to check out to the placeholder right before pushing it to remote repository. The rest is self explanatory; deleting the master branch and push it to the remote repository should work now. Excerpted from [here](http://matthew-brett.github.com/pydagogue/gh_delete_master.html).

Comment: It would fail on git push remote :master if this is checked on remote side - you will see "remote: error:" as prefix in the error log lines.

Answer (score 2):

Log in at the server, go to the Git directory and rename the branch in the bare repository.

This does not have all the problems associated with reuploading the same branch. Actually, the 'clients' will automatically recognize the modified name and change their remote reference.

Afterwards (or before) you can also modify the local name of the branch.

Comment: I have forgotten the credentials to log on to the github server. Anybody with credentials out there :-P

Answer (score 2):

**OK**, renaming a branch both **locally** and on **the remote** is pretty easy!...

If you on the branch, you can easily do:

`git branch -m <branch>`

or if not, you need to do:

`git branch -m <your_old_branch> <your_new_branch>`

Then, push deletion to the remote like this:

`git push origin <your_old_branch>`

Now you are done.

If you get an upstream error while you trying to push, simply do:

`git push --set-upstream origin <your_new_branch>`

I also created the image below to show the steps on a real command line. Just follow the steps and you would be good:

[image]

Comment: your suggestion to push deletion didn't work, i needed to run this: git push origin --delete <your_old_branch>

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
git checkout old-branch-name
git push remote-name new-branch-name
git push remote-name :old-branch-name
git branch -m new-branch-name
```

Comment: messes up with branch tracking - users may have to fix their branch locally?

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest and most 'readable' way I know of:

#### 'Move' local branch using -m

```
git branch -m my_old_branch_name my_new_branch_name
```

#### Push the 'moved' branch to the remote, set 'upstream' using -u

```
git push origin -u my_new_branch_name
```

Setting 'upstream' essentially 'connects' your local branch to the remote, so that things like fetch, pull and push will work.

#### Delete the old branch from the remote

```
git push origin -D <old_name>
```

Your local branch is already gone, because you 'moved' it in the first step.

Answer (score 1):

### Updated solution for 2022

GitHub is now officially supporting its users in renaming branches and making the guidance available on [GitHub Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-branches-in-your-repository/renaming-a-branch).

I have followed their steps and successfully renamed both of my local and remote branches.

In case the URL becomes broken, here are the solutions.

#### Rename remote branch

1. On GitHub.com, navigate to the **main page** of the repository.
2. Above the list of files, click **Branches**.
   [image]
3. In the list of branches, to the right of the branch you want to rename, click on the **edit** symbol.
   [image]
4. Type a new name for the branch and review information, then click **Rename branch**
   [image]

#### Updating a local clone after a branch name changes

As per GitHub Docs:

> After you rename a branch in a repository on GitHub, any collaborator with a local clone of the repository will need to update the clone.

From the local clone of the repository on a computer, run the
following commands to update the name of the default branch:

```bash
$ git branch -m OLD-BRANCH-NAME NEW-BRANCH-NAME
$ git fetch origin
$ git branch -u origin/NEW-BRANCH-NAME NEW-BRANCH-NAME
$ git remote set-head origin -a
```

Optionally, run the following command to remove tracking references to the old branch name:

```bash
$ git remote prune origin
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do the following:

```
git -m master master-old #rename current master
git checkout -b master   #create a new branch master
git push -f origin master #force push to master
```

But force pushing is a bad idea if other people are sharing this repository. Force push will cause their revision history to conflict with the new one.

Answer (score 0):

The following can be saved to the shell script to do the job:

For example:

```
remote="origin"

if [ "$#" -eq 0 ] # if there are no arguments, just quit
then
    echo "Usage: $0 oldName newName or $0 newName" >&2
    exit 1
elif
    [ "$#" -eq 1 ] # if only one argument is given, rename current branch
then
    oldBranchName="$(git branch | grep \* | cut -d ' ' -f2)" #save current branch name
    newBranchName=$1
else
    oldBranchName=$1
    newBranchName=$2
fi

git branch -m $oldBranchName $newBranchName

git push $remote :$oldBranchName # Delete old branch on remote
git push --set-upstream $remote $newBranchName # Add new branch name on remote and track it
```

Please note that here default remote name "origin" is hard-coded. You can extend the script to make it configurable!

Then this script can be used with Bash aliases, Git aliases or in, for example, [Sourcetree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlassian#Acquisitions_and_product_announcements) custom actions.

Answer (score 0):

Go to github.com or wherever it is, click branch, and rename it. Then run these locally:

```
git branch -m <old-branch-name> <new-branch-name>
git fetch origin
git branch -u origin/<new-branch-name> <new-branch-name>
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe the key is the realization that you are performing a *double* rename: `master` to `master-old` and also `master-new` to `master`.

From all the other answers I have synthesized this:

```
doublerename master-new master master-old
```

where we first have to define the `doublerename` Bash function:

```
# doublerename NEW CURRENT OLD
#   - arguments are branch names
#   - see COMMIT_MESSAGE below
#   - the result is pushed to origin, with upstream tracking info updated
doublerename() {
  local NEW=$1
  local CUR=$2
  local OLD=$3
  local COMMIT_MESSAGE="Double rename: $NEW -> $CUR -> $OLD.

This commit replaces the contents of '$CUR' with the contents of '$NEW'.
The old contents of '$CUR' now lives in '$OLD'.
The name '$NEW' will be deleted.

This way the public history of '$CUR' is not rewritten and clients do not have
to perform a Rebase Recovery.
"

  git branch --move $CUR $OLD
  git branch --move $NEW $CUR

  git checkout $CUR
  git merge -s ours $OLD -m $COMMIT_MESSAGE

  git push --set-upstream --atomic origin $OLD $CUR :$NEW
}
```

This is similar to a history-changing `git rebase` in that the branch contents is quite different, but it differs in that the clients can still safely fast-forward with `git pull master`.

Answer (score -6):

```
git update-ref newref oldref
git update-ref -d oldref newref
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me, I get:  git update-ref trunk trunk2
fatal: trunk2: not a valid SHA1

Comment: An explanation would be in order.