# Renaming a branch

Tags: git, version-control

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [git: rename remote branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526794/git-rename-remote-branch)

Hi,

I want to rename a local branch that's also pushed as a remote repository how can I rename them both?

Comment: vote to close, duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526794/git-rename-remote-branch

Comment: It's not actually a duplicate as the suggested question asks specifically about "master" which has caveats (like it can't be deleted) which make the answer confusing, if you just want to rename any branch