# Rename remote branch

Tags: git

I have created a local branch X that at some point I pushed to remote server (origin)

```
git push origin X
```

I realized it's a bad idea to have branch named X and want it to be called Y
The problem is that I've already pushed the branch to the repository.

Is it safe to delete it from the server and push it under a new name like this ?

```
push origin :X

// 'clone ' the branch under a new name locally ( X-> Y)

push origin Y
```

What will happen to the people that already fetched from the server. Say that they already
made a branch locally based on the old X name *BUT* they did not make any changes locally or pushed them to the server for the old X branch.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526794/git-rename-remote-branch can help too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

other people will keep a pointer to branch X (as `origin/X`) in their repository until they run `git remote prune origin`. it's left as a *stale branch*

when fetching/pulling they will get a second point to (newly created) branch Y (as `origin/Y`)

branching and merging is not affected by this.

so, as long as all commits are still reachable from your branch, renaming is fine.

Answer (score -1):

If others have pulled the branch to their local repositories it is not safe to delete it. One route to consider is deleting all the files from the old branch. Leave a README pointing to the new branch.