# How do I make GitHub properly reflect that I've locally changed the name of a branch?

Tags: git, github

I created a branch named "javascript-checkpoint". Then I pushed that branch to GitHub.

Then I locally changed the name of "javascript-checkpoint" to "explore-checkpoints".

Then I did git push, thinking that would make it so that GitHub would show explore-checkpoints in place of javascript-checkpoint. But GitHub showed no branch named explore-checkpoints, only javascript-checkpoint. I then did 'git push origin explore-checkpoints', and git told me:
    * [new branch]      explore-checkpoints -> explore-checkpoints
So the branch was not on GitHub until I pushed it as a new branch. Now GitHub is showing javascript-checkpoint and explore-checkpoints as two separate branches. Locally, I have only explore-checkpoints. How do I make GitHub show the same?

I found a similar question ( [Rename remote branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981889/rename-remote-branch) ) but the asker of that one is more concerned than I am with making it so others can still pull from his repository. I only care about making it so one other person can *look* at my code. I am the only person who *edits* code in this repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any particular reason why simply deleting the "javascript-checkpoint" branch isn't an option?

If you want to just delete the extra branch, simply run `git push origin :javascript-checkpoint` to delete the remote branch.

Comment: I thought the explore-checkpoints branch on GitHub did not include commits I made on javascript-checkpoint. Now I see that it does. Which I should have checked earlier by looking at explore-checkpoints on GitHub. Thanks.

Comment: @Coleman remember that a `git` branch is just a label we put to a commit.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply delete your previous remote branch

```
git push :javascript-checkpoint
```

Your first push was still using the remote tracking branch used the first time:

```
git push  explore-checkpoint:javascript-checkpoint
```

Which is why you didn't see a second branch right away.

Comment: Note that with a recent git1.7.11+ Git, the push policy changes by default: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9749477/6309

Comment: What does your second command mean (git push  explore-checkpoint:javascript-checkpoint)?

Comment: @Coleman it is how your git push was translated after renaming your branch locally : the associated upstream branch was still there, with its original name.