# How not to ignore the message "not found in upstream origin, using HEAD instead"?

Tags: git, shell, deployment, warnings, clone

I am writing shell script to deploy a `git` branch from a remote repo.

This is the command I am using:

```
   git clone -q --depth=1 https://my.repourl.com/git-repo.git /my/destination/folder -b develop
```

The problem is, if the branch (develop in this case) is wrong, it just ignores and pulls from the master branch (?). I get this message:

```
  warning: Remote branch devel not found in upstream origin, using HEAD instead
```

I just want git to die/exit, if it does not find the branch specified. Any flags for that?
Or any alternatives? `git-archive` did not work for some reason.

Comment: Parse the output from `git ls-remote` first to make sure the branch exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [twalberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1253222/twalberg) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393004/how-not-to-ignore-the-message-not-found-in-upstream-origin-using-head-instead#comment21760995_15393004), **[`git ls-remote --heads https://my.repourl.com/git-repo.git`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote)** is the command to use for checking if a branch exists on the remote side.

The question "[How to check if remote branch exists on a given remote repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8223965/6309)" lists the other possibility:

```
git clone -n
git fetch
# parse git branch -r
```

---

The test (bash) can look like:

```
br=$(git ls-remote --heads https://my.repourl.com/git-repo.git|grep abranch)
if [[ "${br}" != "" ]]; then
  git clone -b aBranch ...
fi
```

Comment: Well, I have to do this in Shell Script and check the status of each command (success/fail). But the question actually how NOT to ignore warnings when branch does not exist when cloning?

Comment: @KevinRave and the answer is to *not* clone because you have detected *before* that the branch doesn't exist.

Comment: I got your point. So this is going to be done in two steps. Check if repo and branch exist and then do a clone, if branch exists. I thought  if I could do this in one shot. :-)

Comment: BTW, can you elaborate your answer and write the `git` commands completely, so that it is useful to others?

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same behavior as posted by Kevin with git v1.7.1 - but when testing with git v2.12.0, the **clone** command *does* actually fail when a non-existing branch is specified :

```
$ git clone --depth 1 -b FakeBranch --bare gitserver:/repo.git
Cloning into bare repository 'repo.git'...
warning: Could not find remote branch FakeBranch to clone.
fatal: Remote branch FakeBranch not found in upstream origin
```

Comment: It seems to be the case since 1.7.10: https://github.com/git/git/commit/920b691fe4da8115f9b79901411c0cc5fff17efe