# Check if "remote" is indeed a git remote

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-remote

Say I have a list of strings like so:

```
remotes/origin/master
remotes/origin
origin/master
origin
```

how can I tell if the beginning of the string is a valid remote? For example,

```
remotes/origin
origin
```

should both be valid remotes, in general, right? How to determine that though?

Comment: `remotes/origin` is very probably not a valid remote name, in what context are you trying to use this?

Answer (score 3):

Hokay, to answer the actual question (instead of the one I saw-what-I-expected-to-see from the examples):

```
git config --local --get-regexp "^remote\\.$yourname\\.url" >&- \
&& echo it\'s a remote
```

should serve nicely.  I carry aliases for frequently-used option combos, the one I'd be using here is

```
git config --global alias.grl '!f() { git config --local --get-regexp "${@-.}"; }; f'
```

so the test I'd actually use for my own work would be

```
git grl "^remote\\.$yourname\\.url" >&-  && echo it\'s a remote
```

To test for a remote-tracking-branch name, the question I answered on my  first attempt, it's

```
[[ `git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name $anything` = refs/remotes/* ]] \
&& echo it\'s a remote
```

or

```
case `git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name $anything` in
refs/remotes/*)  echo yes ;;
esac
```

if you you're not using `bash`.

Comment: This tests for a valid *remote-tracking name*, but not for a valid *remote* (which matches the examples, but not the question itself). Note that double square brackets is a bash construct: in old POSIX sh you can use `case`.

Comment: Gak. I saw the examples and kinda read what I expected to read as the question.

Comment: p.s. I'd forgotten `[[` is a bashism, thanks for the reminder @torek

Answer (score 2):

`origin` is a real [git remote](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) - a construct that contains URI of remote repository your local clone interacts with.

`origin/master` OR `remotes/origin/master` refer to version of `master` branch available on remote `origin`, these two can be used interchangeably as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588291/git-branching-master-vs-origin-master-vs-remotes-origin-master).

I'd recommend checking out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18137175/in-git-what-is-the-difference-between-origin-master-vs-origin-master) for more details (your question may be a duplicate?).

As for the answer to 'how do I check if this is a valid remote' - there's no built-it way that I'm aware of but [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223906/how-to-check-if-remote-branch-exists-on-a-given-remote-repository) lists some nice ideas how to chain git commands to check.

Answer (score 2):

This is a strange way to look at names in git... Any name goes. All your examples could be local branches. It would be unnecessarily confusing but nothing keeps you from naming a local branch

```
remotes/something
```

Then if you push it to your upstream, your remotes list will show something like

```
remotes/remotes/something
```

I'd say from a contextless string you can't assume anything.

To check if some string matches one of your repo's remotes

```
git branch -r | grep yourString
```

should do the trick.

Comment: right, so how would you check to see if a given string is a git remote for that repo?

Comment: @AlexanderMills have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223906/how-to-check-if-remote-branch-exists-on-a-given-remote-repository), sadly (?) no accepted answer there.

Comment: @orthej2 Great answer there, thanks for the link :-) However, it adresses a specific context (no locally updated remotes). `git branch -r` is simpler if available.