# How to find out which of 'master' or 'main' branches exists in a repository?

Tags: bash, git, branch

I'm working on a Bash script that does some Git repository maintenance. Some of repositories use `'master'` as the main branch while others use `'main'`. What Git command can I use to return the first branch of these which exists?

P.S. I want to check local branches of a repo, since there will always be a local `'master'` or `'main'` branch.

Comment: You'd have to define "the first which exists". If you meant the first which has been created, git doesn't keep that kind of branch metadata. But you might want to check `git config --get init.defaultbranch` on recent enough git repos.

Comment: @RomainValeri that would only tell you which would be the default branch when initializing a new repo, not of the current one

Comment: Not the first which has been created, just the first from the list which exists. I assume there will be one of these. BTW, `git config --get init.defaultbranch` doesn't return anything for me.

Comment: what do you do if both exist?

Comment: @MarcusMüller As I said, there will always be just one of them. Why would you need to have both?

Comment: @planetp for example, a medium-sized FOSS project I work closely with migrated to `main`. But they couldn't just waltz in and immediately delete `master`, because there's people (and projects) whose automation depends on the name of branches, so `master` and `main` both exist, but `master` simply sees no further updates.

Answer (score 9):

To find out which of the two *local* branches exists, you can use [`git branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) with the `-l`/`--list` option:

```
git branch -l master main  # outputs 'master' or 'main', provided only one exists
```

Git also marks the current branch with an asterisk, so you could add `--format` to prevent that:

```
git branch -l main master --format '%(refname:short)'
```

Comment: Better use `git branch -l master main | sed -r 's/^[* ] //' | head -n 1`: removes the first double space or space star according to the current branch state, then remove any other result line which could corrupt the variable content.

Comment: `git branch -l main master --format '%(refname:short)'` is more stable for use in scripts than sed, feel

Answer (score 4):

To find out what some *other* Git repository's `HEAD` is, use `git ls-remote`:

```
$ git ls-remote --symref origin HEAD
ref: refs/heads/master  HEAD
670b81a890388c60b7032a4f5b879f2ece8c4558    HEAD
```

This assumes both your Git, and the remote's Git, are not so old that they do not support `--symref` (it must be supported on both sides).  Note that this command can be run outside any repository by using a URL directly, instead of a remote name like `origin`.

To find out what branch names exist in some other Git repository, either clone it and inspect the resulting remote-tracking names, or use `git ls-remote`.  Note that you can specify just `refs/heads` to limit the output to branch names only, or omit it entirely to get everything (all branch and tag names and any other names they choose to expose).

Answer (score 3):

> What Git command can I use to return the first branch of these which exists?

`git branch -r` returns a list of remotes.
`grep origin/ma` will match `main` and `master`.
If you need to be pickier, use `grep -E 'origin/(main|master)'`

Assigning the list returned to an array should work, but be wary of names with spaces &c because the array elements are delimited by whitespace and the whole thing can blow up.

```
b=( $(git branch -r | grep origin/ma ) ) # all matches
git checkout "${b[0]##*/}"               # first hit
```

If you want to be a little more careful,

```
for n in main master; do 
  b="$(git branch -r -l "origin/$n")"
  if [[ -n "$b" ]]; then
    git checkout "${b[0]##*/}"
    break # keep the first success
  fi 
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, "default branch" has no meaning *locally*; it only makes sense if your repo is a remote to someone else, or in terms of a remote that someone else hosts. (Also, in terms of "what branch do I pull by default when I pull from this local branch, but if you knew that, you wouldn't be asking this.)

```sh
git fetch
git branch -r --list 'origin/HEAD' | grep '>'
```

Comment: Interestingly, this produces empty output for some (active) repos. What would that mean?

Comment: Interesting! What does `git branch -r --points-at origin/HEAD` tell you for these?

Comment: `error: malformed object name 'origin/HEAD'`

Comment: @planetp does that repository even have a remote called `origin`?

Comment: yes, it's otherwise a pretty 'standard' repository.

Comment: well without a remote, what does "default" branch even mean: hence the first sentence in my answer!

Answer (score 1):

> I want to check local branches of a repo, since there will always be a local `master` or `main` branch

Taking that as a reliable description of your intended use-case environment, since in general use it's often enough not true,

> What Git command can I use to return the first branch of these which exists?

A concise way of doing it is

```
if git cat-file -e refs/heads/master 2>&-; then echo master
elif git cat-file -e refs/heads/main 2>&-; then echo main
fi
```

but for anything even a little more elaborate you're likely to want for-each-ref,

```
{ git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/{heads,remotes/*}/master;
  git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/{heads,remotes/*}/main;
} | sed -E 's,(.*)/,\1 ,' | sort -usk1,1
```

which gives the answer for local branches and all tracked remotes without any foofaraw.

In my `git` repo this reports `refs/remotes/origin master`, for instance, and the Git project keeps both branch names in lockstep. But as someone else pointed out, some projects keep `master` around as a record of where it was when they switched away, and as you might have noticed I *don't* have a `master` or `main` branch. My `make` branch tracks `origin/next`, that's the one I run my deployments from, and there's a couple others for little projects.

To do just local branches do

```
{ git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads/master;
  git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads/main;
} | head -1
```

See [the `for-each-ref` examples](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#_examples), it was built for this.

Comment: I thin you could simplify the last command into `git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads/master refs/heads/main`. What do you think, @jthill?

Comment: @EdSabol OP specified a priority, f-e-r sequences its output based on the results not the request so it wouldn't do what OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted a script that worked with multiple remotes (origin fork or canonical upstream) and repositories that used main or master. Based on Paul Hodges answer I ended up with:

```
#Update local/fork default to match remote. Can also delete current local branch using -D (to clean up a finished feature branch)
gum(){
  REMOTES=( $(git branch -r | grep -Eo "  (origin|upstream)/(master|main)") )
  RNAME=${REMOTES[-1]%%/*}    # Prefix of last one in the list (prefer fetching from upstream over origin)
  RBRANCH=${REMOTES[-1]##*/}  # Suffix of last matching remote
  LBRANCH="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"  # Name of current checked out branch

  if [[ "$LBRANCH" != "$RBRANCH" && "$1" != "-D" ]]; then
    echo "error current branch is '$LBRANCH' not $RBRANCH and -D not specified to delete current branch"
  elif [[ ! -z $(git status -s) ]]; then
    echo "error pending changes on local branch"
  else
    # Switch to local default, delete current if requested
    if [[ "$LBRANCH" != "$RBRANCH" && "$1" == "-D" ]]; then
      git checkout $RBRANCH
      git branch -D $LBRANCH
    fi
    # fetch all and prune, then update local default
    git fetch --all -p && git merge $RNAME/$RBRANCH && if [[ "$RNAME" != "origin" ]]; then
      git push ${REMOTES[0]%%/*} $RBRANCH # also update default branch on fork
    fi
  fi
}
```