# Delete git master branch on a private server (not GitHub)

Tags: git, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I have a project hosted on my own personal git server (it is not on GitHub). The `master` branch is a stale old cookie, and I don't need it anymore.

A couple of months ago I created a `0.8/develop` branch off of `master` and since then we've gone through `0.8/master`, `0.9/develop`, `0.9/master` and we're currently on `1.0/develop`. I'd like to get rid of the `master` branch, mainly because it doesn't match the naming convention that we've established. It's just a matter of housekeeping.

I found several related questions on SO, as well as a blog post, but they all seem to be specific to use of GitHub, and not my own private server:

- [I can't delete a remote master branch on git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12208751/i-cant-delete-a-remote-master-branch-on-git)
- http://matthew-brett.github.io/pydagogue/gh_delete_master.html

These both specifically say something to the effect of:

> You need to go to the main GitHub page for your forked repository, and
>   click on the 'Settings' button.

Of course, this is not an option as I'm not using GitHub. I'm guessing that I can edit the contents of the config file in my bare repo to achieve the same results. Is that correct? The config file currently looks like this:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = true
        logallrefupdates = true
        ignorecase = true
        precomposeunicode = false
        sharedRepository = group
[remote "origin"]
        url = file:///Library/WebServer/Documents/loupe
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
```

I have two questions:

1. Should I set my default repo to my current working branch (`1.0/develop`), or the oldest branch that's left (`0.8/develop`)?
2. What modifications do I need to make to the config file to set the default repo?

Comment: `git push origin :master`, `git remote prune origin`

Comment: @madhead remote: error: By default, deleting the current branch is denied, because the next
remote: error: 'git clone' won't result in any file checked out, causing confusion.

Comment: Basically you're trying to do something that you really don't need to do. Just leave master out of date, or keep it up to date, whatever you choose. There's no reason to delete it.

Comment: @NathanBouscal I agree that I don't *need* to delete it, but I *want* to.

Comment: The feedback Git is giving you is telling you why deleting it is a bad idea. What will people who clone your repo have checked out by default? You're basically putting in a substitute master that points to something else, because there has to be a default branch. Why not just have that default branch be master to begin with?

Comment: @NathanBouscal We're versioning our repo, so the default should probably be `0.9/master` or `1.0/develop`

Comment: Versions should be tags. I'd recommend this: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First decide which branch should be the *default branch* when the repository is cloned. I assume `new_master` for this example.

On one of the clients create the `new_master` branch on the remote repository, you may use anything for `master` instead, e.g. a commit or another branch name, or skip this step if you already have a suitable branch on the remote.

```
git push origin master:new_master
```

The next step **can't** be done from remote, so execute the command in your remote repository (e.g. using SSH):

```
cd /path/to/my_git_repo
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/new_master
```

Alternatively, change the content of the `HEAD` file directly.

Back on the client:

```
git fetch
git remote show origin
```

You should see that the `HEAD` points to `new_master` instead of `master` (or that `HEAD` is ambiguous if you set `new_master` to be `master`). Now we can remove the old master:

```
git push origin :master
```

Git shouldn't complain anymore about the deletion. Finally, set the local `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`:

```
git remote set-head origin -a
```

Comment: Awesome! Would you advise choosing the older `0.8/develop` or the newer `1.0/develop` as the new master...or does it matter?

Comment: It's just the branch which is checked out when someone clones the repository for the first time. Our `master` / `HEAD` reflects the current production state, while other branches are used for active development. But that's just our workflow. Set it to whatever fits your workflow.

Comment: This is even more relevant now with GitHub leading the industry in changing the language of technology. (https://github.com/github/renaming/) I found this StackOverflow question/answer because I want to rename my 'master' branch to 'main'. Thank you.