# delete github main branch?

Tags: git, github

Just created a new github account, and noticed that i am unable to delete the main branch using this command:

```
git push origin :main
```

This returns the error:

```
 ! [remote rejected] main (refusing to delete the current branch: refs/heads/main)
 error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:accountname/reponame.git'
```

Any idea why i cant delete this branch? It hints at not being able to delete the "current" branch, but i am on another branch ..

Comment: `main` is likely the "default" branch and your repo must have a default branch. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12208843/6889416 What is it bigger picture task that you are trying to do? Rename the default branch? Switch to another default branch?

Comment: Yes, i want to use master as default branch. Thanx for the link, that was what i was looking for ;)

Comment: Since you are using GitHub I recommend doing it on github.com. https://github.com/<ownername>/<reponame>/settings/branches. GitHub has support so old links redirect that I am not sure applies if you do this manually.