# git fetch remote branch and remote ref

Tags: git

how do I fetch a remote branch and update git's local ref for that branch without effecting the current branch?  For example if I do this

```
$ git pull origin master
```

origin/master is merged into my current branch. This also doesn't work

```
$ git fetch origin master
```

As then I check

```
$ git branch -r -v
origin/HEAD   -> origin/master
origin/master 7cf6ec5 test 02
```

that origin/master ref "7cf6ec5 test 02" is behind. The real origin/master is a "XXXXXX test 03".  `git fetch` only pulled the changes into FETCH_HEAD it didn't upload the local origin/master ref. What's the step for updating that ref?

Note:

```
$ git fetch origin
```

Will get all remote refs and update them but unfortunately that's (a) a lot of clutter. (I don't want someone else's 30-50 random branches knowing that someone wouldn't want mine) and (b) as branches are deleted on origin those refs don't get deleted locally the next time I do `git fetch origin` which means that path ends up with cruft.

The question is, how do fetch just one branch and update its ref locally?

Answer (score 11):

I think what I'm looking for is this

```
$ git fetch origin master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

That does seem to work in that unlike 'git fetch origin master' I do actually see the ref get updated.

Any reason that's the wrong answer? Something I should be scared of?

Answer (score 2):

You can always provide a refspec to the `git fetch` command.  In particular, if you want to update `other-branch`, you can do:

```
git fetch origin other-branch:other-branch
```

That will fetch the current tip of `refs/heads/other-branch` from origin, and put it into a local branch of the same name.

Another way, is to go ahead and to:

```
git fetch origin other-branch
```

And then recreate the local branch:

```
git branch -l -f other-branch -t origin/other-branch
```

The `-l` is there as a safety mechanism.  It'll create a reflog entry, so that you can get back to the previous version if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

```
git fetch origin
```

this will fetch all remote branches and update the remote tracking branches for them.

Now you can do either one of two things

```
git checkout other-branch
git merge origin/other-branch
git checkout -
```

or

```
git push . origin/other-branch:other-branch
```

The last option is ok if you know it's going to be a fast forward merge.

Comment: Thanks. How do I just fetch and update origin/master. I don't want all 30 or 50 branches from the remote repo. In fact, I just tried `git fetch origin`. Then I deleted a branch on origin. Then I did `git fetch origin` again and I see the branch ref that was deleted on origin is still in my local repo when I do `git branch -r -v`

Comment: tracking branches are not deleted on a fetch. You need git remote prune for that.

Comment: What is the difference between `git fetch origin` and `git fetch --all`?

Comment: If you have more than one remote, `--all` will update remote tracking branches for each one.