# git: how to rename a branch (both local and remote)?

Tags: git, repository, rename, git-branch

I have a local branch `master` that points to a remote branch `origin/regacy` (oops, typo!).

How do I rename the remote branch to `origin/legacy` or `origin/master`?

I tried:

```
git remote rename regacy legacy
```

But this gave an error:

> error : Could not rename config section 'remote.regacy' to 'remote.legacy'

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526794/rename-master-branch-for-both-local-and-remote-git-repositories

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I rename a local Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591213/how-do-i-rename-a-local-git-branch)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rename master branch for both local and remote Git repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526794/rename-master-branch-for-both-local-and-remote-git-repositories)

Comment: Related question: [Renaming branches remotely in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4753888/3216427)

Comment: **In short:** 1. Checkout to the local branch, 2. `git branch -M new-name` 3. `git push -d origin old-name` 4. `git push -u origin new-name`.

Comment: Great answer! I would just re-organise 1. Checkout of branch `old name` 2. Rename `git branch –m old-name new-name` 3. Checkout into new branch `git checkout new name` 4. Push changes to new remote `git push -u origin new-name` 5. Go to the web page create PR in GH, you will see the new branch as well as the old branch 6. Back to branch `new name` you can now delete the origin head of the old branch `git push -d origin old-name` the local and remote now will have only one branch with all the commits in the new branch. The old branch has been safely deleted AFTER new branch created.

Comment: Adjacently related: [How can I push a local Git branch to a remote with a different name easily?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5738797/4561887)

Answer (score 2632, accepted):

[image: schematic, cute git remote graph]

---

There are a few ways to accomplish that:

1. Change your local branch and then push your changes
2. Push the branch to remote with the new name while keeping the original name locally

#### Renaming local and remote

```sh
# Rename the local branch to the new name
git branch -m <old_name> <new_name>

# Delete the old branch on remote - where <remote> is, for example, origin
git push <remote> --delete <old_name>

# Or shorter way to delete remote branch [:]
git push <remote> :<old_name>

# Prevent git from using the old name when pushing in the next step.
# Otherwise, git will use the old upstream name instead of <new_name>.
git branch --unset-upstream <new_name>

# Push the new branch to remote
git push <remote> <new_name>

# Reset the upstream branch for the new_name local branch
git push <remote> -u <new_name>
```

[image: console screenshot]

---

#### Renaming Only remote branch

Credit: [ptim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30590083/how-do-i-rename-both-a-git-local-and-remote-branch-name/30590238#42173564)

```sh
# In this option, we will push the branch to the remote with the new name
# While keeping the local name as is
git push <remote> <remote>/<old_name>:refs/heads/<new_name> :<old_name>
```

---

#### Important note:

When you use the `git branch -m` (move), Git is also **updating** your tracking branch with the new name.

> `git remote rename legacy legacy`

`git remote rename` is trying to update your remote section in your configuration file. It will rename the remote with the given name to the new name, but in your case, it did not find any, so the renaming failed.

**But** it will not do what you think; it will rename your **local** configuration remote name and **not** the remote branch.

---

**Note**
Git servers might allow you to rename Git branches using the web interface or external programs (like Sourcetree, etc.), but you have to keep in mind that in Git all the work is done locally, so it's recommended to use the above commands to the work.

Comment: You still need to do something, after the above and when I try to pull I get message: `Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref ''refs/heads/old_name'`

Comment: Is there a way to avoid automatic closure of the open PRs on the old-name branch on the remote? Faced this in gitlab, where the PR on the old branch name was closed after pushing to origin.

Comment: Here is a single-command version of this: `OLD=<old>; NEW=<new>; REMOTE=<remote>; git branch -m $OLD $NEW && git push $REMOTE --delete $OLD && git push $REMOTE $NEW && git push $REMOTE -u $NEW`

Comment: If the ```<old_name>``` branch you're trying to rename is set as the default remote branch, then you need to change the default remote branch to some other branch else ```git push <remote> --delete <old_name>``` will fail.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer! What will see other developers when I've done these changes with these 6 commands? What will they have to do on their local machines connected with the old branch name?

Comment: When I run the unset as described in the answer and the comments, I get: "fatal: Branch <old_name> has no upstream information"

Comment: @JimArcher yes because you need to use the new name rather than old name. I changed it but the original author changed it back without explanation.

Comment: Would this work for a Visual Studio project that's housed remotely in Azure DevOps? Let's say the remote main branch in ADO has been renamed, and I need to rename branch locally to match.

Comment: Maybe you can remove the last but one command `git push <remote> <new_name>` since it is included in the last one `git push <remote> -u <new_name>`.

Comment: I got error when do it for main branch: 
```
 ! [remote rejected] main (refusing to delete the current branch: refs/heads/main)
error: failed to push some refs to
```
Firstly, I needed to push <new_name> branch to develop and then change default branch in GitHub settings (more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040754/deleting-remote-master-branch-refused-due-to-being-the-current-branch)

Comment: I found the CLI sequence in this answer worked fine but for GitHub users who want some confirmation this GitHub article steps through process using GitHub web interface, in case you like that sort of thing: https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-branches-in-your-repository/renaming-a-branch

Comment: could you clarify the difference between <remote> and <old_name> in your code snippet? For example you could construct sample command where <old_name> != <remote> and use it comments of your code block.

Comment: As far as I can see steps 4 and 5 are not required because step number 6,) doing git push <remote> -u <new_name> does them anyway.   This works in my git version 2.44.0 anyway.

Comment: `git` kept tracking the old branch for me until I ran the step:
`git branch --unset-upstream <new_name>`

Answer (score 694):

If you have named a branch incorrectly AND pushed this to the remote repository follow these steps to rename that branch ([based on this article](https://multiplestates.wordpress.com/2015/02/05/rename-a-local-and-remote-branch-in-git/)):

1. **Rename your local branch:**

   - If you are on the branch you want to rename:
     `git branch -m new-name`
   - If you are on a different branch:
     `git branch -m old-name new-name`
2. **Delete the `old-name` remote branch and push the `new-name` local branch**:
   `git push origin :old-name new-name`
3. **Reset the upstream branch for the new-name local branch**:
   Switch to the branch and then:
   `git push origin -u new-name`

Comment: After the first 2 steps, if you get an error message about the current branch points to a non-existence branch on the remote repo, the 3rd step fixes this

Comment: @Dr1Ku Need to know the difference between `git push <remote> --delete old_name` & `git push origin :old-name new-name` to delete a branch.

Comment: BitBucket users: fix error on Step 2 if renaming `master`, in Repo Details set the default branch to new branch. The error is: `By default, deleting the current branch is denied, because the next 'git clone' won't result in any file checked out, causing confusion.

You can set 'receive.denyDeleteCurrent' configuration variable to 'warn' or 'ignore' in the remote repository to allow deleting the current branch, with or without a warning message.

To squelch this message, you can set it to 'refuse'.

error: refusing to delete the current branch: refs/heads/master`

Comment: For Github and Bitbucket users, when you run Step 2, it will create the new remote branch, but you will see an error from the remote about "refusing to delete the current branch". So just go to Repository Settings ➔ Branches ➔ **Change Default / Main Branch** ➔ new_branch_name ➔ Save. Then run Step 2 again, so that it deletes the old remote branch name.

Comment: Would this work for a Visual Studio project that's housed remotely in Azure DevOps? Let's say the remote main branch in ADO has been renamed, and I need to rename branch locally to match.

Comment: This is the best answer by far.

Comment: In Azure DevOps, you need to disable all branch policies, as having set **any** policy will deny pushing directly to the branch. Go to `Project Settings` -> `Repositories` -> `YourBranch` -> tab `Policies` and toggle all policies to `Off`.

Comment: Worked for GitHub as is without any changes.

Answer (score 179):

Check on which branch you are using the command below

```
git branch -a
```

Checkout to the branch you want to rename

```
git checkout branch_to_rename
```

Rename the branch using

```
git branch -m new_name
```

Push the changes

```
git push origin :old_name new_name
```

Comment: Does this delete the old branch on remote?

Comment: @Nomnom It does

Answer (score 121):

- **Rename your local branch**.

If you are on the branch you want to rename:

```
git branch -m new-name
```

if you stay on a different branch at the current time:

```
git branch -m old-name new-name
```

- **Delete the old-name remote branch and push the new-name local branch.**

Stay on the target branch and:

```
git push origin :old-name new-name
```

- **Reset the upstream branch for the new-name local branch.**

Switch to the target branch and then:

```
git push origin -u new-name
```

Comment: `git push origin :old-name new-name` closed my open PR. Careful if you have an ongoing discussion in your PR.

Comment: Before entering the `git push origin :old-name new-name` command, make sure your default remote branch is not set to the current branch you want to rename and delete

Answer (score 57):

It seems that there is a direct way:

> If you really just want to rename branches remotely (without renaming any local branches at the same time) you can do this with a single command like
>
> `git push <remote> <remote>/<old_name>:refs/heads/<new_name> :<old_name>`
>
> *[Renaming branches remotely in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753888/renaming-branches-remotely-in-git/21302474#21302474)*

See the original answer for more detail.

Comment: Didn't work in git `2.20.1` Deleted the old branch but the new one was not created.

Comment: Btw, just in case if you're initialized empty repository and set up origin - you will need extra fetch command before invoking rename. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13928822/2338477

Answer (score 46):

It can also be done the following way.

*At first rename local branch, then remote branch.*

**Renaming the local branch:**

If logged in another branch,

```
git branch -m old_branch new_branch
```

If logged in the same branch,

```
git branch -m new_branch
```

**Renaming remote branch:**

```
git push origin :old_branch    // Delete the remote branch

git push --set-upstream origin new_branch   // Create a new remote branch
```

Answer (score 42):

## To rename a local branch

```
 git branch -m <old_name> <new_name>
```

> Rename your local branch from `master` to `legacy`

```
git branch -m master legacy
```

---

## To rename a remote branch

> - Delete the remote branch with the old name.
> - push the local branch with the new name to the remote repository.

```
git push origin :regacy

git push origin legacy
```

> - `git push origin :regacy` deletes the remote branch named `regacy`.
> - `git push origin legacy` pushes the local branch named legacy to the remote repository and creates a new remote branch named `legacy`.

Comment: that will cause the error `Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'refs/heads/<BRANCH>'` when you pull, to fix you have to run `git push origin -u <NEW_NAME>`

Answer (score 30):

**Renaming Git Branch Locally and Remotely:**

1. Start by switching to the local branch which you want to rename:

   **git checkout <old_name>**
2. Rename the local branch by typing:

   **git branch -m <new_name>**
3. At this point, you have renamed the local branch. If you’ve already pushed the <old_name> branch to the remote repository, perform the next steps to rename the remote branch.

   **git push origin -u <new_name>**
4. Delete the <old_name> remote branch:

   **git push origin --delete <old_name>**

✅ That’s it. You have successfully renamed the local and remote Git branch.

Comment: Great to hear that my answer helped you.

Answer (score 27):

If you have already pushed the wrong name to remote, do the following:

1. Switch to the local branch you want to rename

   `git checkout <old_name>`
2. Rename the local branch

   `git branch -m <new_name>`
3. Push the `<new_name>` local branch and reset the upstream branch

   `git push origin -u <new_name>`
4. Delete the `<old_name>` remote branch

   `git push origin --delete <old_name>`

This was based on [this article](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-rename-local-and-remote-git-branch/).

Answer (score 25):

Attaching a Simple **Snippet** for renaming your current branch (local and on origin):

```
git branch -m <oldBranchName> <newBranchName>
git push origin :<oldBranchName>
git push --set-upstream origin <newBranchName>
```

**Explanation** from git docs:

> **git branch -m** or -M option,  will be renamed to
>   . If  had a corresponding reflog, it is renamed
>   to match , and a reflog entry is created to remember the
>   branch renaming. If  exists, -M must be used to force the
>   rename to happen.
>
> **The special refspec :** (or +: to allow non-fast-forward updates)
>   directs Git to push "matching" branches: for every branch that exists
>   on the local side, the remote side is updated if a branch of the same
>   name already exists on the remote side.
>
> **--set-upstream**
>   Set up 's tracking information so  is considered 's upstream branch. If no  is specified, then it defaults to the current branch.

Answer (score 14):

#### Git Rename your Branch

**Rename Local Branch**

- Current Branch: `git branch -m new-name`
- Different Branch: `git branch -m old-name new-name`

**Update Remote Branch**

- `git push -d origin old-name`

**Set New Upstream**

- `git push origin -u new-name`

Comment: Deleting and making a new one could be seen as Renaming, but it's not really, when you delete the old branch, your PR will be closed on such a branch for example. Just to be aware there might be side effects to deleting and new creating branches.

Answer (score 6):

There is no direct method,

1. **Rename Local Branch**,

   My current branch is **master**

   `git branch -m master_renamed` **#master_renamed is new name of master**
2. **Delete remote branch,**

   `git push origin --delete master` **#origin is remote_name**
3. **Push renamed branch into remote,**

   `git push origin master_renamed`

That's it...

Comment: Nice and simple and only 3 steps. Only improvement I can suggest is `git push -u origin master_renamed` to set the branch as a tracking branch

Answer (score 6):

Another workaround is the following:

1. Checkout to the branch you want to change
2. Create a new branch from it
3. Set upstream to remote
4. Delete old branch from local and remote

**More specifically:**

```sh
# Checkout to the branch you want to rename
git checkout <old_branch_name>

# Create a new branch from the old one and checkout to it
git checkout -b <new_branch_name>

# Push the new branch to remote
git push -u <origin> HEAD

# Delete local branch
git branch -d <old_branch_name>

# Delete remote branch
git push <origin> -d <old_branch_name>
```

Answer (score 4):

Branches in a Git repository hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com) can be renamed using the repository settings. As a side effect, branch protection rule(s) in GitHub will be changed, too.

1. Visit "Branches" in your repository settings: `https://github.com/<name>/<repository-name>/settings/branches`
2. Rename branch
   [image: Branches page in GitHub repository settings]
3. Everyone using this repository has to do locally:

> ```
> $ git fetch
> $ git checkout <new_name>
> ```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done even without renaming the local branch in three simple steps:

1. Go to your repository in GitHub
2. Create a new branch from the old branch which you want to rename
3. Delete the old branch

Answer (score 2):

I use these git alias and it pretty much does the job automatic:

```
git config --global alias.move '!git checkout master; git branch -m $1 $2; git status; git push --delete origin $1; git status; git push -u origin $2; git branch -a; exit;'
```

> Usage: git move FROM_BRANCH TO_BRANCH

It works if you have the default names like master, origin etc.
You can modify as you wish but it gives you the idea.

Answer (score 2):

Along with the other steps others have laid out, **remember**:

In the event that you are trying to delete the `default` branch, e.g. `master`, you will get this error when running `git push origin :<branch_name>`

`! [remote rejected] master (refusing to delete the current branch: refs/heads/<branch_name>) error: failed to push some refs to '<repo_name>'`.

### a) Change the `default` before deleting the branch (Github example)

1. Go to your repo.
2. Click on "Settings"
3. Change the `default` branch as shown in the picture below:

[image]

### b) Then delete the [target] remote:

`$ git push origin :master`

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure the local branch has the correct, new name.
The appropriate command is `git branch -a`.

Now delete the branch with the old, incorrect name from the remote repository.
To do this, use the following command
`git push origin --delete <old-name>`

Verify that the old branch has been deleted properly.
Now add the branch with the correct name.
For this, use the command `git push origin -u <new-name>`

Lastly, perform a reset of the upstream branch to ensure that the changes are effective.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the following task to rename local and remote branch:

```
# Rename the local branch to the new name
git branch -m <old_name> <new_name>

#  Delete the old remote branch
git push origin --delete <old_name>

# push to new remote branch - creates new remote branch
git push origin <new_name>

# set new remote branch as default remote branch for local branch
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<new_name> <new_name>
```

Comment: How is it different than existing answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a **single command** to **rename the current branch**, like this:

```
git rename my-new-branch-name
```

Then, you have to create a file named `git-rename`, make it executable (`chmod +x git-rename`) and save it to a folder in your `$PATH`, containing [this](https://github.com/elifarley/shellbase/blob/master/bin/git-rename):

```
#!/bin/sh
currentBranch="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"
test $# != 1 && cat <<EOF && exit 1
Renames the current branch ($currentBranch) both locally and remotely.
USAGE:
git rename <new branch name>
EOF

newBranch="$1"; shift
git branch -m "$newBranch" && \
git push origin :"$currentBranch" "$newBranch"
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename remote branch only:

```
(set -ex; old=oldname; new=newname; git push origin origin/$old:refs/heads/$new :$old)
```

or:

```
git-rr() (set -ex; old=$1; new=$2; git push origin origin/$old:refs/heads/$new :$old)

git-rr oldname newname
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is just create a new branch off of your current branch and then push to remote. Then delete your previous branch (both local and remote).