# How to rename a remote branch using TortoiseGit?

Tags: branch, tortoisegit

I have seen a few questions about this, like:

[How do I rename both a Git local and remote branch name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30590083/how-to-rename-a-remote-git-branch-name)

But I am using [TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/).

As you can see:

[image: Branches]

I recently renamed my local branch from **ImportPTS** to **import-publictalk-names**. I have just pushed my commit from the new named branch to the existing remote named branch.

But I would like the remote named branch to match. Can we do this with TortoiseGit? I tried with the Browser Ref window and couldn't see it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open the push dialog and enter a different name for "remote branch". In order to automatically select the name branch for pushing and pulling, also select "Set upstream/track remote branch". After that the old remote branch can be deleted (e.g., using the log dialog).

Remote branches exist in the remote repository, but also have a "local" corresponding branch named `remotes/NAME/branchname`. Additionally, you have local branches which can have a remote tracked branch, which is a branch name which exists on a remote repository and which is used automatically for pulling and pushing.

Comment: I will try this tonight. Thanks. So I don't need to qualify the remote branch name with a path. Just write the name.

Comment: This answer save my day...once again!