# Change Github branch name

Tags: github

I have a repository in Github with two branches, `master` and `dd`. I gave the name `dd` by mistake and I want to change this name to something else from the Github GUI.

I didn't find a way to do so in the branch webpage:

```
https://github.com/user/repo/tree/dd
```

nor in the branches option page (I do have an option to change what will be the default branch):

```
https://github.com/user/repo/settings/branches
```

How could a branch name be changed in Github?

I work with the command line but yet to have learn Git in a serious way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rename a remote git branch name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30590083/how-to-rename-a-remote-git-branch-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did in the end was this:

First, I duplicated all the data from the wrongly named nonmaster branch to a new, rightly named nonmaster branch, and committed. I double checked that data was committed successfully and indeed there.

Second, after making sure the data was backed up, I navigated to:

```
https://github.com/user/repo/branches
```

I then used the bin icon near the name of the relevant branch and did the rest of the short deleting process from there.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know exactly how to solve it *in* GitHub, but locally you just can:
(Assuming that same repo is locally cloned)

Rename locally:

```
repo (master)$ git branch -m dd new-name
```

Delete remote branch:

```
repo (master)$ git push origin :dd
```

Push all branches again (including the renamed one):

```
repo (master)$ git push --all
```

Answer (score 0):

```
git branch -m old-name new-name
```

look at this link for more details:

https://multiplestates.wordpress.com/2015/02/05/rename-a-local-and-remote-branch-in-git/

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new branch from `dd` via the Branches dropdown:

[image: creating a new branch from develop]

And then delete the old `dd` branch afterwards from the Branches page:

[image: deleting the old branch]