# How to transfer a "Origin/master" branch to a local branch?

Tags: git, devops

I move the "`Origin/master`" branch down to "unit-testing". How can I do it?

This is a screnshot so you can see it:

[image]

Comment: this has nothing to do with c, and probably more to do with git. The image is of (one of many) git clients. Why not include the exact program and version you are using, so that people that know it can answer? Also, the question is not really about programming, but about "how do I do X with program Y".

Comment: It’s not totally clear what you’re asking but my guess is `git pull`.

Comment: I think what you mean is pull `origin/master` into your `local branch` right ? If yes you need `git pull origin master` should work for you . You need to be in to local branch before doing this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30590083/how-do-i-rename-both-a-git-local-and-remote-branch-name/30590238#30590238