# Loosing IntelliSense (suggestions, go to definitions) in visual studio code for C++ project after changing git branch name

Tags: c++, git, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have changed the name of a branch in my GitHub repository (including deleting the old branch name from remote and local). After that in all my C++ source code files the IntelliSense functions such as loading suggestions, go to the definition are not working anymore. I tried to reinstall Visual Studio Code and install the extension for C/C++ IntelliSense. I've checked the Intellisense function in my other project which I did not touch anything, it works properly. I guess there was a problem with my branch in git and try to get back the branch with the old name. But it does not help.

Has anyone gone through this issue? Do you have any suggestions on which was the issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Making a new remote (GitHub) repository with all the same files, using the same git local configuration, and check if you are still having issues with the new repository and same branch.
- Tell another person to fork your GitHub repository, then clone it and check if that person is having the same issues. Or you can just try cloning your original GitHub repository and check.

If the issue is still occurring, check this:

- If C++ is correctly [configure with VS Code using this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp).
- Your VS Code extensions, verify principally the ones related to Git, C++, and IntelliSense, some of them can cause issues.

Remember to use an updated version of VS Code, I found some issues with previous versions of VS Code causing problems with IntelliSense due to the branches.

Additionally, I don't think this one could be the issue, but make sure that you are changing the name of the branch correctly ([check this to verify if you did it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30590083/how-do-i-rename-both-a-git-local-and-remote-branch-name)) or try moving to a different branch and test if you are having issues with all the branches in that repository.