# Why does the behavior of git branch -m differ for macOS and windows versions of git?

Tags: git, github, git-branch, upstream-branch

My colleague and I have been trying to put together a clear, consistent procedure for renaming a git branch locally and remotely.

Assuming we have a branch `oldname` both locally and on remote, and want to rename it to `newname`, and we have checked out locally branch `oldname`, following https://stackoverflow.com/a/30590238/1592322 (and other similar suggestions across the internet), these steps work for my colleague:

```
git branch -m newname
git push --set-upstream origin newname
```

Whereas I have to follow an intermediate step of explicitly unsetting the upstream information (as suggested by user:22992 in that same stack overflow link I provided above):

```
git branch -m newname
git branch --unset-upstream
git push --set-upstream origin newname
```

If my colleague uses my (slightly longer) procedure, then that second additional step `git branch --unset-upstream` results in an error:

```
Fatal: The current branch newname has no upstream branch.
```

So we can't use the same consistent procedure, and guess we just have to watch out for this in general. It seems to me that the behavior of `git branch -m` differs between different git versions. Is this correct? Why is there a difference in behavior?

My colleague is running git version version 2.18.0.windows.1 . Whereas I am running 2.17.2 (Apple Git-113) on a macOS 10.13.6.

Comment: Renaming a branch should not affect its upstream. Perhaps his branch did not have an upstream set initially. You should be able to use `git push -u origin newname` without first running `git branch --unset-upstream` anyway, though. (`-u` is the short spelling for `--set-upstream` with `git push`)

Comment: Thanks @torek. My colleague had already pushed her branch `oldname` previously to remote before the rename. So I would have thought the upstream was set correctly. To your second question, I had tried running  `git push -u  origin newname` to remote, I get the message `Branch 'newname' set up to track remote branch 'oldname' from 'origin'.` . The relationship between the local branch and remote is also clear when you run `git branch -vv`.

Comment: When she ran `git push <remote> <name>`, that would not have set an upstream for `<name>` unless she used the `-u` or `--set-upstream` option, so if it had no upstream, it would continue to have no upstream. Basically the upstream of some branch is either set (to one value, typically something like `origin/master`) or unset: `git branch --unset-upstream` makes it unset, and `git push -u` makes it set—changing or setting it as needed—based on the push. `git branch --set-upstream-to` also makes it set, to whatever you choose.

Comment: I see your point @torek regarding my colleague's specific `git push` command, and could answer that particular source of confusion, thanks! Regarding the other point, I pushed my initial branch `oldname` to remote using `git push --set-upstream origin oldname`. So there is an upstream. But then using `git branch -m newname; git push --set-upstream origin newname` results in `Branch 'newname' set up to track remote branch 'oldname' from 'origin'.`, which is what confuses me.

Comment: Ah - `git push -u` just *always* prints that message, after updating the upstream (perhaps to whatever it already was set to!). The odd thing is, it should be set up to track `newname` from `origin` now, since that is the target of the push.

Comment: Thanks again for the fast response. Unfortunately running `git branch -vv` shows    
<code>
    master  7dcd2fe [origin/master] added test file
    * newname 7dcd2fe [origin/oldname] added test file 
</code>
and looking at remote via the GitHub web interface lists only `oldname` (and `master`) as branches.

Comment: Could it be a case sensitivity issue ? do `oldname` and `newname` only differ in case ? e.g : renaming from `Fix/Something` to `fix/something` ?

Comment: Thanks @LeGEC .Unfortunately not. For this test, I'm _literally_ using `oldname` and `newname` as my old and new branch names respectively.