# How do I rename the local Git branch?

Tags: git, rename, git-branch

I don't want to rename a remote branch, as described in [Rename master branch for both local and remote Git repositories.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526794/rename-master-branch-for-both-local-and-remote-git-repositories?answertab=votes#tab-top)

How can I rename a local branch which hasn't been pushed to a remote branch?

In case you need to rename remote branch as well:
[How do I rename both a Git local and remote branch name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30590083/how-to-rename-a-remote-git-branch-name/30590238#30590238)

Comment: You referenced the answer in both of your questions: `git branch -m <old_name> <new_name>`

Comment: Don't rename the branch, just create a new one at the same place.  (If you then delete the original, I suppose you've accomplished a rename.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
git checkout <old_branch>

git branch -m <new_branch>

git push origin -u <new_branch>
```