# After renaming a git local and remote branch, what should other users of this repository do?

Tags: git

I'm about to rename a branch locally and remotely using the advice provided in the following answer and many more like it:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/30590238/419

The current name of the branch is `coredev` and the new name of the branch will be `newcoredev`.

This is fine for me, it works. But most of these examples appear to assume you're not working with a team with in-flight open feature or bugfix branches created from `coredev` on their own machines.

Is there something extra I need to do or be concerned about to ensure that after renaming `coredev` to `newcoredev` (with its open branches) that won't create a world of pain for my colleagues?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rename master branch for both local and remote Git repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526794/rename-master-branch-for-both-local-and-remote-git-repositories).  See Aristotle's answer and the comments below it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3790682/8910547

Comment: Remember git branches are merely pointers at commits. So you renaming `coredev` to `newcoredev` has zero impact on branches created from `coredev`.  To another user pulling from the central repo, the only thing they need to do is create a new branch tracking `origin/newcoredev`. They don't even have to delete their local `coredev` if they don't want to.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure this is a duplicate, but if it's not, it's not really a *programming* question.   So, I'm going to add this answer here, but it's at least a little bit off topic.

As [jingx noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68278465/after-renaming-a-git-local-and-remote-branch-what-should-other-users-of-this-re#comment120674305_68278465), *Git* does not really care about branch names at all.  It just uses them to find commits.  You can change the spelling of the name as little or as much as you like, e.g., `feature/behavior` can become `feature/behavior` or even `jean-baptiste-emanuel-zorg`, and it all makes no difference at all to Git itself.

There are two places where it *does* matter, though:

1. Each branch, in each repository, can have an *upstream* set.  The upstream of a branch is simply another string, but it's often the string corresponding to the *remote-tracking name* in your repository, which your Git creates or updates based on the *branch* name in some *other* repository.

   When the remote repository Git drops branch name *`B1`* in favor of new name *`B2`*, *your* Git will—let's assume the remote is called `origin` for concreteness here—create your `origin/B2` on your next `git fetch`.  **If** you have enabled `--prune` (`fetch.prune = true`) or use it explicitly, your Git will *also* **delete** your `origin/B1`; if not, it won't.  Either way, the upstream setting of your own branch—let's say you've called your branch `zorg` and set its upstream to `origin/B1`—is now "wrong" in some way as you should change it to `origin/B2`.
2. *Humans* assign significance to branch names.  `feature/behavior`, whether spelled in American or British style, is neutral; `zorg` implies that the branch is evil.  If you're in favor (or favour) of evil, you might want to rename your local branch.

The course of action required for both of these items is the same: tell your co-workers / collaborators / others that you are renaming the branch.  They can take any action *they* need to take, based on this.

Comment: I think git is well within the scope of SO with 134k questions, and it's a developer tool. This is my anon account (to stay out of my employer's radar) and know the SO rules fairly well, I'm a 12 yr veteran of the site :). Thanks for the answer though. I've set up a sandbox to do a dry run both as me as the branch renamer and as a simulated colleague. Will let you know how I get on.

Comment: What I meant is: to the extent that it's on topic, it is a duplicate, as the other links commenters provided cover the mechanics of branch renaming. The rest is more software-engineering...