# Rename remote branch on bitbucket

Tags: git, github, gitlab, bitbucket

Is it possible to rename a remote branch on Bitbucket?

I found a command to do it locally `git branch -m old-name new-name`.

But not sure if this is the correct way and what will happen when I push it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30590238/7976758 Pushing the new branch ad deleting the old one is probably the way to go. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+rename+remote+branch

Answer (score 2):

For remote branches, regardless of BitBucket or any other platform, can be renamed by:

```bash
# Ensure your are on the correct branch
git checkout <old-branch-name>

# Ensure you have the whole remote branch history
git pull

# Remove the remote branch
git push origin --delete <old-branch-name>

# Pust the local branch remotely with the new name
git push origin --set-upstream <new-branch-name>

# Rename branch locally
git branch -m <old-branch-name> <new-branch-name>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Delete the Old Branch and Create a New One

Since branches are pointers, creating a new branch under a different name and destroying the old branch is identical to renaming the branch. **Make sure you start on the blob that you want your branch to be on.**

Delete the old branch locally.

```
git branch -D <old_branch>
```

Delete the remote branch.

```
git push origin -d <old_branch>
```

Create your new local branch.

```
git branch <new_branch>
```

Create a new branch in the remote and link your local branch to it.

```
git push --set-upstream origin <new_branch>
```

### Bonus Stuff

This is related: `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> <branch>` will link a local branch to the remote in the event where they are unlinked. Also, if you have a branch in the remote that you do not have locally, you can simply use the command, `git switch <branch>` and it will create a linked local branch for you, then it switches to that.