# change branch into new master github

Tags: github

When I type "git branch" i get this:

```
Zachs-MacBook-Pro:stocks1 zachsmith$ git branch
  77e98af109bd63630b38c1f1ca3937d43715ddf4
  add_bootstrap
  add_stock_model
  master
  stocks_download
  temp
* working
  working#2(backup)
```

Does this mean i am on "working" branch of the detached head "77e98af109bd63630b38c1f1ca3937d43715ddf4"?

i want where I am now to become the new master on github, but I am not sure how to do that without merging things. basically I would be happy to just re-write the master with where I currently am.

How can I do this?

Comment: the reason i want to do this is i want to push it to heroku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this mean I am on "working" branch of the detached head "77e98af109bd63630b38c1f1ca3937d43715ddf4"?

No, it just means:

- you are on the working branch nammed  "`working`"
- there is another branch named "`77e98af109bd63630b38c1f1ca3937d43715ddf4`" (probably some mishap in the `git branch` command)

> basically I would be happy to just re-write the master with where I currently am.

You can [rename the remote master](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4754132/6309)

```
git branch old_master origin/master
git push origin old_master
```

And force push your working branch

```
git push --force origin working:master
```

You would see a similar approach in "[Rename `master` branch for both local and remote Git repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1526794/6309)".

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple options in order to do that, one is to delete the master branch and rename your working branch as master, but you might know you can be sentenced up to 25 years of jail and death penalty for that.

You can also rename your old master branch and rename your working branch as the new master, or (my favourite way) you can use the `-s ours` flag so you keep your master intact and you overwrite everything from your working branch:

```
git checkout working
git merge -s ours master
git checkout master
git merge working
```

And your master now will match to your working branch.

Comment: thanks. would this mean that the "working" branch then becomes the local master? also I have noticed that after merging you get these notifications of where the mergers happen, e.g.<<<<<<<<<<< HEAD. Is there any way to avoid that?