# Rename merged branch name in bitbucket

Tags: git, branch, bitbucket, git-branch

I'm new to Bitbucket. I've few merged branches in remote and I need to rename these with issue's name. Is there any way to rename these. While searching, I found a hack but I think deleting the branch and pushing it back is neither a good practice nor efficient since I've large number of branches that need to be rename.
Any appreciation will be appreciated.Thank you

Comment: In my opinion move your problem outside of Bitbucket.
Git supports rewrite of commits but it requires a lot work. Have you see this link https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch ?

Comment: Maybe to late! But see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753888/git-renaming-branches-remotely

Answer (score 1):

**Remember, branches are only labels on commits.**

Therefore, if you change a lot of branches on local and then push them to server, nothing but the labels are transmitted.

If you have a lot of branches to rename, just create any sort of script to deal with the creation of new, pushing, deletion of old on remote, deletion of old on local...