# How to change topic name of Gerrit via command line

Tags: git, gerrit

We can set initial topic name by:
**git push origin HEAD:refs/heads/master/topic_name**
But I wonder how could I change the topic name via command line later on?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you searching for renaming the branch name? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591213/how-do-i-rename-the-local-branch)

Answer (score 2):

You can set the topic using REST

https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#set-topic

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful.

Answer (score -1):

Simply [push your local branch under a different name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21302474/6309):

```
git push <remote> <remote>/<old_name>:refs/heads/<new_name> :<old_name>
```

In your case:

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/heads/master/<new_name> :refs/heads/master/topic_name
```

Here, you push:

- your local branch under a new remote name
- "nothing" to the old branch (which is then deleted)

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way just using gerrit command instead of using git push, consider you don't have repo cloned locally.