# Rename git bucket branch name after pull request

Tags: git, gitbucket

I am working on BitBucket and stuck in one issue. I need to rename the remote branch after pull request. I don't want to loose any review comments as well.

Looks like , there are so many stack over flow link on this topic but personally i did not get clear ans or might be i did not get proper link.

I was following below link but after upstream new branch, i need to raise another PR on this. which i don't want.please suggest me.

[Renaming branches remotely in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753888/renaming-branches-remotely-in-git)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do the renaming locally in your repository. But before, delete the branch in *Bitbucket*, do a fetch in your local clone to update it (if doing it from Sourcetree, make sure you check prune tracking branches, from cmd use `git fetch -p`). Then you can **rename** the branch and *push* it back to Bitbucket.

Look at this link [https://www.w3docs.com/](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/git/how-to-rename-git-local-and-remote-branches.html)

And here is another link to a step by step explanation [https://phoenixnap.com/](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-rename-git-branch-local-remote)