# Bulk Move remote git branches from one directory to another

Tags: git

I need to bulk move remote git branches from one directory to another

My current setup:

```
remote:
      Origin
            bug 
               bug1_abcbug
               bug2_xyzbug
               .
               .
               .
               bug50_bug
            
            bugfix
                bug51
                bug52
                .
                .
                .
                Bug200
```

Now, I want to move all 50 branches from the 'bug' folder to the 'bugfix' folder.
I know I can individually rename the branch name and its remote name.
However, is there any easier way to just bulk move all branches from one folder to another ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Branches don't come in "folders".

Comment: Agree! something how it is set up at the place where I am trying to solve it.

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you're trying to accomplish. Can you please replace your "setup currently" with the output of something like `git branch -r` if you're asking about renaming branches, or something like `ls` if you're talking about renaming files.

Comment: You can certainly write a script that renames a bunch of branches. But if these are on the remote it's not so easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in 3 steps:

1. Run `git fetch`
2. Identify the command to isolate the 50 branches. In your example it might be something like (in a *nix shell):

```
git branch -r | grep origin/bug/bug
```

3. Loop through the list of branches, and for each branch name, use your tool of choice to parse out the branch name after the 1st '/' character (`bug/bug1...`), and again after the 2nd '/' character (`bug1...`), and then use those strings in conjunction with [this command (or function)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21302474/184546) to rename the branch remotely:

```
git push <remote> <remote>/<old_name>:refs/heads/<new_name> :<old_name>
```