# Redmine Git repo out of synch after branch rename

Tags: git, redmine, git-branch

I have a git post-receive script that pushes to a second, bare repo, which is used by Redmine to track git commits. Recently, I renamed branch FOO to BAR, but it doesn't look like the Redmine repo has picked this up. How can I let the bare repo know that the branch has been renamed?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can rename remote branches. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526794/git-rename-remote-branch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short there is no easy way to let the bare repository automatically know that the branch has been renamed. There is a degree of manual intervention needed to get it to work. The steps outlined in the link by Ryan Pendleton should fix it for you.

I used to host my own Redmine and Git servers myself, but it was for reasons like this that I moved to using GitHub as a source code repository and FogBugz to manages cases.