# Repoint git-svn master branch back to trunk

Tags: git-svn

I'm not sure how I got into this state, but my `master` branch on my local git-svn repo seems to be pointing to the remote UAT branch.

```
git status
# On branch master nothing to commit (working directory clean)
git svn dcommit Committing to https://svn...com/MyRepo/branches/UAT ...
```

how do I fix this?

Comment: It'd help to know exactly what you're trying to "fix". There's nothing wrong with having the local master branch be based off a remote branch; indeed that's how I normally operate my repository.

Answer (score 5):

I *think* what you're trying to fix is that your local "master" branch is based on the remote UAC branch, as opposed to the remote trunk. If you're happy to lose your commits, you can simply run the below, which will checkout the trunk and then move the master branch to your current point.

```
git checkout remotes/trunk
git checkout -B master
```

If you don't want to lose your commits, `git rebase` is your friend. Use the below:

```
git rebase $(git merge-base remotes/UAC master) master --onto remotes/trunk
```

This works out the common parent of the UAC branch and the local master branch, makes all the commits from there to the tip of the master branch onto the trunk, then moves the master branch to point there.

Comment: I got myself in the same situation somehow (merged the wrong branch into master?) and the `checkout` solution fixed it for me. Would accept this answer if I could.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to rename the current master branch and to checkout origin/trunk as (new) master branch.

```
git branch -m master uat
git checkout origin/trunk master
```

If you need you can now cherry-pic commits from the uac branch to master (I would use `gitk --all` to help me with this)

A little more complex problem:
[Rename master branch for both local and remote Git repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526794/git-rename-remote-branch)