# Renaming a branch in GitHub

Tags: git, github, branch, rename

I just renamed my local branch using

```
git branch -m oldname newname
```

but this only renames the local version of the branch. How can I rename the one on GitHub?

Comment: possible duplicate of [git: rename remote branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526794/git-rename-remote-branch)

Comment: Have you checked in the admin settings? My current project on github doesn't have any branches but you can rename the repo there so I would think you could rename branches as well.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal Nope, you cannot rename a Git branch from the GitHub site.

Comment: The answers for this question are nearly universally wrong. The question is not how to rename a git branch, it's how to rename a **github** branch. Many things on github are tied to a branch which means any answer needs to cover those things. For example renaming **master** to **main**

Comment: @gman For what it's worth, it seems these answers answered the spirit of the OP's question. The OP's question may not have been perfectly phrased, from a technically exacting standpoint, or the relevant issue you are currently looking into. But then, this question isn't coming from a deep technical background of either git or GitHub. From this perspective, one can consider this a "beginner" or elementary question. As such, it is phrased, & answered appropriately for this audience. Frustrating, sure, but I think this Q, these Answers are appropriate/relevant, esp for pre BLM git/Hub usage Q's.

Comment: If the answers are only git then this entire question should be close as a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30590083/how-do-i-rename-both-a-git-local-and-remote-branch-name). The only thing that makes it not a duplicate is it's about github not git and therefore the answers need to cover the differences between git and github.

Answer (score 392, accepted):

As mentioned, delete the old one on GitHub and re-push, though the commands used are a bit more verbose than necessary:

```
git push origin :name_of_the_old_branch_on_github
git push origin new_name_of_the_branch_that_is_local
```

Dissecting the commands a bit, the `git push` command is essentially:

```
git push <remote> <local_branch>:<remote_branch>
```

So doing a push with no local_branch specified essentially means "take nothing from my local repository, and make it the remote branch".  I've always thought this to be completely kludgy, but it's the way it's done.

As of [Git 1.7](https://github.com/gitster/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.0.txt) there is an alternate syntax for deleting a remote branch:

```
git push origin --delete name_of_the_remote_branch
```

As mentioned by @void.pointer in the comments

> Note that you can combine the 2 push operations:
>
> `git push origin :old_branch new_branch`
>
> This will both delete the old branch and push the new one.

This can be turned into a simple alias that takes the remote, original branch and new branch name as arguments, in `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
    branchm = "!git branch -m $2 $3 && git push $1 :$2 $3 -u #"
```

Usage:

```
git branchm origin old_branch new_branch
```

Note that positional arguments in shell commands were problematic in older (pre 2.8?) versions of Git, so the alias might vary according to the Git version. See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321492/git-alias-with-positional-parameters) for details.

Comment: Note that you can combine the 2 push operations: `git push origin :old_branch new_branch`. This will both delete the old branch and push the new one.

Comment: Is there any reason why the new branch can't be pushed before deleting the old?  I personally prefer processes where the delete operation happens after the create operation is successful, just in case something goes wrong.

Comment: Really good question, and yeah, you do have to delete the old branch first (otherwise it'll fail as it's not a FF update).  If you're concerned though you can just create a copy of the old branch before starting.

Comment: Does not work. It will simply put the branch back on Github with its old name.

Comment: @geoff: seems to work for me, could you be more specific?

Comment: @AdamParkin 1. `git branch -m new_branch` (rename old_branch to new_branch) 2. `git commit -m 'msg'`, 3. `git push` 4. Mhmm, old_branch shows up in Github, Google question and I am led to your answer 5. `git push origin :old_branch` (says it deleted) 6. `git push origin new_branch`... completes then says `* [new branch]  new_branch -> old_branch`.  Go back to Github and `old_branch` shows up again.  If I delete in Github web UI, I have the option to "Restore," so it seems like pushing the new_branch is just restoring.

Comment: If I would be removing the old branch and making a new branch, wouldn't that also be making multiple commits on the remote?

Comment: No, this isn't Mercurial, making a branch does not introduce a new commit.

Comment: Note that this is essentially creating a new branch with the same commits.

For example, if you have an open pull request with the old branch, you will have to make another one from the new branch.

Comment: One thing to be aware of is that when you rename the branch, any pull requests you have open against that pull request will be automatically closed.  We had to rename the branch back and then reopen manually all of the pull requests....

Comment: @geoff this worked on github: `git branch -m oldbranch newbranch; git push origin --delete oldbranch; git push origin newbranch:newbranch`

Comment: To github.com:user/user.github.io.git
 * [new branch]      main -> main
 ! [remote rejected] master (refusing to delete the current branch: refs/heads/master)
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:username/username.github.io.git'  it doesn't seem to work if you only have 1 branch - master in my case.

Answer (score 60):

The following commands worked for me:

```
git push origin :old-name-of-branch-on-github
git branch -m old-name-of-branch-on-github new-name-for-branch-you-want
git push origin new-name-for-branch-you-want
```

Comment: This is the brief answer that works. BTW, the first command could also be put as last one in the answer.

Comment: Actually, I just did this twice and it worked on github.

Comment: Should be the accepted answer - nice and simple. Thanks!

Comment: Important to mention that you need to have the branch checked out, or else the first command just deletes the remote branch.

Comment: how does this impact child branches of `old-name-of-branch-on-github` ?  Will they become children of `new-name-for-branch-you-want` ?

Comment: can i delete the old branch after following these steps?

Comment: yes, you can delete that branch

Answer (score 42):

I've found three commands on how you can change your Git branch name, and these commands are a faster way to do that:

```
git branch -m old_branch new_branch         # Rename branch locally
git push origin :old_branch                 # Delete the old branch
git push --set-upstream origin new_branch   # Push the new branch, set local branch to track the new remote
```

If you need step-by-step you can read this great article:

*[How to Rename Git Local and Remote Branches](http://www.w3docs.com/snippets/git/how-to-rename-git-local-and-remote-branches.html)*

Comment: `git push --set-upstream` is the most important part if you happen to change the branch name locally using github app before deleting remote branch.

Answer (score 26):

### Rename branches in Git local and remote

**1. Rename your local branch.**

If you are on the branch you want to rename:

```
git branch -m new-name
```

If you are on a different branch:

```
git branch -m old-name new-name
```

**2. Delete the old-name remote branch and push the new-name local branch.**

```
git push origin :old-name new-name
```

**3. Reset the upstream branch for the new-name local branch.**

Switch to the branch and then:

```
git push origin -u new-name
```

So the conclusion is:

```
git branch -m new-name
git push origin :old-name new-name
git push origin -u new-name
```

Comment: This is for git and GitHub is under git so it will work and it works with me and with others

Comment: It doesn't work. Try first and second steps `git branch -m new-name && git push origin :master new-name`. It will fail. If this answer is only about git and not github then this question is a duplicate of several other questions and should be closed. If it really is about github then the answer has to cover github. This answer does not.

Comment: For me I only needed to do steps 1 and 2, and this process worked

Answer (score 17):

You can do that without the terminal. You just need to create a branch with the new name, and remove the old after.

> ### Create a branch
>
> In your repository’s branch selector, just start typing a new branch
> name. It’ll give you the option to create a new branch:
>
> [image: Create a branch]
>
> It’ll branch off of your current context. For example, if you’re on
> the bugfix branch, it’ll create a new branch from bugfix instead of
> master. Looking at a commit or a tag instead? It’ll branch your code
> from that specific revision.
>
> ### Delete a branch
>
> You’ll also see a delete button in your repository’s Branches page:
>
> [image: Delete a branch]
>
> As an added bonus, it’ll also give you a link to the branch’s Pull
> Request, if it has one.

I just copy and paste this content from: *[Create and delete branches](https://github.com/blog/1377-create-and-delete-branches)*

Answer (score 14):

Just remove the old branch and create new one.

Example (solely renaming the remote branch):

```
git push origin :refs/heads/oldname
git push origin newname:refs/heads/newname
```

You also probably should rename local branch and change settings for where to push/pull.

Comment: Shouldn't the 2nd command be `git push origin newname:refs/heads/newname` ?  master and newname may not point to the same commit.

Comment: "master" is just as example, will change now.

Comment: Maybe the order of two commands should be reversed (i.e. upload new name first, remove old after that)

Comment: @gman, Doesn't renaming it Git-wise also rename it Github-wise?

Comment: Try it. `git push origin :refs/heads/master`

Comment: @gman, Should remove master branch, unless it is marked as protected.

Answer (score 14):

On GitHub side, you can use the new (Jan. 2021) "[Support for renaming an existing branch](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-01-19-support-for-renaming-an-existing-branch/)" (protected branches can only be renamed by admins, see the end)

Follow this tutorial: https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/renaming-a-branch

[image: rename branch dialog -- https://i2.wp.com/user-images.githubusercontent.com/2503052/105069955-a231fa80-5a50-11eb-982c-a114c9c44c57.png?ssl=1]

See "[How do I rename branch on the GitHub website?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65799365/6309)".

This is a better approach, because renaming a branch that way (on github.com) will ([source](https://github.com/github/renaming/tree/040636ea50e945875c70cc964d586f645e9bd810#renaming-existing-branches)):

- Re-target any open pull requests
- Update any draft releases based on the branch
- Move any branch protection rules that explicitly reference the old name
- Update the branch used to build GitHub Pages, if applicable
- Show a notice to repository contributors, maintainers, and admins on the repository homepage with instructions to update local copies of the repository
- Show a notice to contributors who git push to the old branch
- Redirect web requests for the old branch name to the new branch name
- Return a "Moved Permanently" response in API requests for the old branch name

---

Update Dec. 2021:

> ### [Restrict renaming protected branches to admins](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-12-16-restrict-renaming-protected-branches-to-admins/)
>
> Now, only admins can rename branches that are protected by branch protection rules.
>
> GitHub allows repository collaborators to rename every branch in a repository, with the exception of the default branch.
>
> When a collaborator renames a branch, any non-wildcard branch protection rules that apply to that branch are also changed to match the branch's new name.
>
> Because only admins can modify branch protection rules, renaming of a protected branch is now limited to admin users.
>
> For more information, visit [Renaming a branch](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-branches-in-your-repository/renaming-a-branch) and [Managing a branch protection rule](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/managing-a-branch-protection-rule).

Comment: Unfortunately as of writing, the "re-target any open pull requests" part is only true for "base" branches, and "regular" branches associated to a pull-request will still close the PR in question.

Answer (score 11):

**Simple as that**. In order to rename a Git branch locally and remotely use this snippet (tested and works like a charm):

```
git branch -m <oldBranchName> <newBranchName>
git push origin :<oldBranchName>
git push --set-upstream origin <newBranchName>
```

Explanation:

1. Rename step:

> Git reference:
> **With a -m or -M option**, <oldbranch> will be renamed to <newbranch>. If
> <oldbranch> had a corresponding reflog, it is renamed to match
> <newbranch>, and a reflog entry is created to remember the branch
> renaming. If <newbranch> exists, -M must be used to force the rename
> to happen.

2. Delete step:

> Git reference:
> **git push origin :experimental** Find a ref that matches experimental in
> the origin repository (e.g. refs/heads/experimental), and delete it.

3. Update on remote repository step (upstream reference for tracking):

> Git reference:
> **--set-upstream** For every branch that is up to date or successfully pushed, add upstream (tracking) reference, used by argument-less
> git-pull[1] and other commands. For more information, see
> branch.<name>.merge in git-config[1].

Answer (score 3):

Here is what worked for me:

1. Create the new branch first:

   ```
   git push github newname :refs/heads/newname
   ```
2. On the GitHub site, go to settings and change the *Default branch* to `newname`
3. Delete the `oldname`

   ```
   git push github --delete oldname
   ```

Answer (score 3):

This is an added condition in [Hazarapet Tunanyan's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4311535/hazarapet-tunanyan) answer.

```
git branch -m old_branch new_branch         # Rename branch locally


git push origin :old_branch                 # Delete the old branch
# You might be getting an error doing the above step, skip to the next step

git push --set-upstream origin new_branch   # Push the new branch, set local branch to track the new remote
```

You get an error doing `git push origin :old_branch` because **old_branch** you are trying to delete might be the **default branch**.

Just do the other 2 steps and then goto github and change the default branch from the settings, then you will be able to do `git push origin :old_branch`.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to **rename the following files**:

1. Navigate your project directory.
2. Rename `.git/refs/head/[branch-name]` to `.git/refs/head/new-branch-name`.
3. Rename `.git/refs/remotes/[all-remote-names]/[branch-name]` to `.git/refs/remotes/[all-remote-names]/new-branch-name`.

Rename **head and remotes** both on your local PC *and* on origins(s)/remote server(s).

#### Branch is now renamed (local and remote!)

---

### Attention

If your current *branch-name contains slashes* (`/`) Git will create the directories like so:

**current branch-name:** `"awe/some/branch"`

- `.git/refs/head/awe/some/branch`
- `.git/refs/remotes/[all-remote-names]/awe/some/branch`

**wish branch-name:** `"new-branch-name"`

1. Navigate your project directory.
2. Copy the `branch` file from `.git/refs/*/awe/some/`.
3. Put it in `.git/refs/head/`.
4. Copy the `branch` file from all of `.git/refs/remotes/*/awe/some/`.
5. Put them in `.git/refs/remotes/*/`.
6. Rename all copied `branch` files to `new-branch-name`.
7. Check if the directory and file structure now looks like this:

- `.git/refs/head/new-branch-name`
- `.git/refs/remotes/[all-remote-names]/new-branch-name`

8. Do the same on all your remote origins/servers (if they exist)

- **Info**: on remote-servers there are usually no refs/remotes/* directories because you're already on remote-server ;) (Well, maybe in advanced Git configurations it might be possible, but I have never seen that)

#### Branch is now renamed from `awe/some/branch` to `new-branch-name` (local and remote!)

#### Directories in branch-name got removed.

---

***Information:** This way might not be the best, but it still works for people who might have problems with the other ways*

Answer (score 1):

This article shows how to do it real easy.

1. To rename a local Git branch, we can use the Git branch -m command to modify the name:

   ```
    git branch -m feature1 feature2
   ```
2. If you’re just looking for the command to rename a remote Git branch, this is it:

   ```
    git push -u origin feature2:feature3
   ```

   Check that you have no tags on the branch before you do this. You can do that with `git tag`.

Comment: What does *"This article"* refer to? Please respond by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/33715993/edit), not here in comments.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I needed an additional command,

```
git branch --unset-upstream
```

to get my renamed branch to push up to `origin newname`.

(For ease of typing), I first `git checkout oldname`.
Then run the following:

`git branch -m newname <br/>` git push origin :oldname`*or*`git push origin --delete oldname 
**`git branch --unset-upstream`** 
`git push -u origin newname` *or* `git push origin newname`

This extra step may only be necessary because I (tend to) set up remote tracking on my branches via `git push` **`-u`** `origin oldname`. This way, when I have `oldname` checked out, I subsequently only need to type `git push` rather than `git push origin oldname`.

If I do **not** use the command `git branch --unset-upstream` before `git push origin newbranch`, git *re-creates* `oldbranch` and pushes `newbranch` to `origin oldbranch` -- defeating my intent.

Comment: @gman Point taken. My solution uses git locally to rename a branch on GitHub, remotely, after renaming it on the local git copy of the GitHub repository. So perhaps it could be considered a specialized solution, for when you want to use the command line, rather than the GitHub website interface, and you have a local clone that you also would like updated. Thanks for highlighting this distinction, and clarifying that this answer is for a special case, rather than a general solution.

Comment: The problem is github ties features to branches. Try renaming master to main and your instructions will fail.

Answer (score 1):

### Branch Rename is now available through GitHub API

You can [**rename a branch with the GitHub REST API**](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/branches#rename-a-branch).

And you can easily [**run API commands via the `gh` CLI**](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_api) all like this:

```sh
gh api "repos/{owner}/{repo}/branches/{branch}/rename" -f new_name={newBranch}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Download Atlassian Sourcetree (free).
2. Import your local clone of the repository.
3. Right click your branch to rename, in the sidebar. Select "Rename branch..." from context menu, and rename it.
4. Push to *origin*.

Comment: Thanks, but I had to switch to the branch as well as importing it.

Comment: The link is broken (404).

Answer (score -1):

The following commands rename the branch locally, delete the old branch on the remote location and push the new branch, setting the local branch to track the new remote:

```
git branch -m old_branch new_branch
git push origin :old_branch
git push --set-upstream origin new_branch
```

Comment: Although your code snippet might solve the issue, you should describe what’s the purpose of your code (how it solves the problem). Furthermore, you might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score -1):

On the Git branch, run:

```
git branch -m old_name  new_name
```

This will modify the branch name on your local repository:

```
git push origin :old_name new_name
```

This will push the modified name to the remote and delete the old branch:

```
git push origin -u new_name
```

It sets the local branch to track the remote branch.

This solves the issue.

Answer (score -2):

#### Three simple steps

- `git push origin head`
- `git branch -m old-branch-name new-branch-name`
- `git push origin head`

Comment: Doesn't work. All it did is create a new branch on github. It didn't rename the branch. https://pastebin.com/dDh06HEb