# Sending pull request for different issues-Github

Tags: git, version-control, github

I have forked a repository, cloned it to get a local copy to work on two issues.Let's call them Issue 1 and Issue 2 . Firstly,I applied three commits which addresses the problem faced in Issue 1. Then I did `git push origin master` to push the changes from my local master branch to origin/master. After this I sent a pull request to fix Issue 1. So Issue 1's pull request has three commits attached to it.

After that to address Issue 2, I created another branch called `upstream` via `git checkout -b upstream upstream/master` (I believe this adds a remote upstream (which is the same url as that of origin) and gives me a local branch `upstream` which starts off from `upstream/master`).

Now I make two commits to address Issue 2, cherry-pick the two commits with `git cherry-pick <SHA>` (which just gave me 'nothing to commit' message). After this I did `git push origin upstream` to populate the changes in my local upstream branch with that in origin. When I sent a new pull request to Issue 2, the three commits of Issue 1 got attached with the two commits I made to address Issue 2. Messing everything up.

(Later I also made a 4th commit to `origin/master` to address a problem in Issue 1 which implies the pull request to Issue 1 ,now has 4-commits attached to it.)

Then locally I made a commit to upstream branch addressing Issue 2. What do I want now ? I want to be able to push this commit and update this commit to Issue 2's pull request ALONE and I want to separate the 4-commits involved in Issue 1 from the 3-commits involved in Issue 2.

Everything is a bit messed up as of now. I am new to git and github,can someone please help me with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Everything is a bit messed up as of now.

That is because the idea of making pull request from your fork is *always* to make them from a dedicated branch, *never* from `master` (or any other branch which can evolve on the upstream original repo)

Plus, you don't create a *branch* name `upstream`, you add a remote named `upstream` referencing the first repo that you have forked, in order to track `upstream/master` (the master from the original repo).

See "[Pull new updates from original Github repository into forked Github repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3903835/6309)".

[image]

At any moment you would then be able to do:

```
git checkout master
git pull upstream master

git checkout issue1
git rebase master
git push -f origin

git checkout issue2
git rebase master
git push -f origin
```

If you had pull requests done for `issue1` and `issue2`, the `push -f` (which rewrites the commits of those branches) would trigger an automatic update of your pull request, without you having to do anything.

See more at "[Couple tips on pull-requests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14681796/6309)".

---

I suspect your situation is this

```
     (master)
--o--o--o--x--x--x (issue1)
                  \
                   y--y--y  (upstream)
```

First: [rename your "`upstream`" branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6591218/6309):

```
 git branch -m upstream issue2
```

Delete your remote upstream branch named "`upstream`" (that will [cancel the associated pull request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20014444/6309), and you will remake a pull request for that issue once we have fixed the branch locally)

```
 git push :upstream
```

Now, make sure you have `master` in sync with the `master` from `upstream` (that is, from the original repo you have forked).
Make sure you don't have work in progress (the `reset --hard` part would erase it)

```
# url of the original repo
git remote add upstream https://github.com/user/repo

git fetch upstream
git checkout master
git reset --hard upstream/master
```

That will make your repo looks like:

```
          O--O (master, upstream/master)
         /
--o--o--o--x--x--x (issue1)
                  \
                   y--y--y  (issue2)
```

Now you need to **rebase** your two issue branches on top of `master`, starting with `issue2`, in order to separate it from `issue1`:

```
 git checkout issue2
 git rebase --onto master issue1 issue2
```

Then `issue1`:

```
git issue1
git rebase master
```

You get:

```
                x--x--x (issue1)
               /
--o--o--o--O--O  (master, upstream/master)
               \
                y--y--y  (issue2)
```

Now, you can push those two branches:

```
git push -f -u origin issue1
git push -f -u origin issue2
```

And make pull requests from there.

Comment: As of now I don't have a branch called issue1 or issue2. I worked on issue1 in master itself (which I now realize is not the right thing to do),but I have done it already. Issue2 is on a branch called upstream (I don't know why I named the branch as upstream). I don't want the commits for issue1 which is on master to interfere with commits for issue2 which is on upstream when I send a pull request. But somehow when I sent a pull request for issue2 from the branch upstream it includes the 4-commits I did for issue1 also -which I don't want. How do I go about this ?

Comment: @user1955184 no problem: you can reset everything the way they are supposed to be set. See my edited answer.