# Change head fork of existing Pull request

Tags: git, github

Is there any way to change head fork of existing pull request?

I have earlier created a pull request with branch A, now I want that PR to take commits from branch B.

Answer (score 0):

If the base ([the branch against which your PR is compared remains the same](https://github.com/blog/2224-change-the-base-branch-of-a-pull-request)), you your PR branch must change its content, you simply can force push a new content:

```
 git checkout B
 git push --force B:A
```

The PR will update its content (new list of commits)

However, the branch A on the fork will keep its original name (`A`), because [you cannot rename a branch involved in a PR on your fork](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20014444/6309).