# How to rename git branch used in pull request Github

Tags: git, github

I made and merged a PR and want to rename the branch I made the PR off of. How can I do this? Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Renaming a branch while on pull request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20007578/renaming-a-branch-while-on-pull-request)

Comment: @Sharad I think this is only for open PRs.

Comment: You can rename the branch wherever you like, but if the merge is already done, this has no effect on the merge. The merge is done.

Answer (score -1):

Editing post to give a reference on how to change the branch name inside an already merged PR. I practically tried this on my side, pushed to GitHub, changed the branch name in the PR that is merged, I can clearly see the change reflecting.

Please follow the below steps:

```
(base) Apples-MacBook-Pro:CrashCall pratapalokraj$ git branch
* Test
  main
(base) Apples-MacBook-Pro:CrashCall pratapalokraj$ git push origin Test
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote:
remote: Create a pull request for 'Test' on GitHub by visiting:
remote:      https://github.com/Blank000/CrashCall/pull/new/Test
remote:
To github.com:Blank000/CrashCall.git
 * [new branch]      Test -> Test
```

After pushing changes in a new branch ( Test ), now I raised a PR with Test branch and merged into main as below and then changed the branch name from Test to Renamed_Test:

[image: Raised a PR]

[image: Merged the PR]

[image: Can see PR being merged]

Click on view all branches from the below screenshot

[image: Go to All branches]

Click on the right most edit button you see down below:

[image: Edit Branch name]

[image: Renaming branch]

[image: Rename window]

[image: Trying to rename]

[image: Renamed completely]

For reference you can also visit this page:

[Rename Branch](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/renaming-a-branch)

Comment: I assume question refers to the renaming of merged PR branch.

Comment: @Sharad Yes, it does.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my misunderstanding, appreciate your efforts. I have added all the steps on how you can change the branch. Please upvote me if you find the answer useful