# Unable to rename git branch to "master", pushes to remote with incorrect name

Tags: git, github, version-control, branch, git-branch

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524933/renaming-a-branch-in-github) SO post as a reference, I was able to rename my `master` to `v1` and now I want to rename my `v2` branch to `master`. I've already changed the default branch to `v1` from GitHub, but when I attempt to rename `v2` to master, the local branch renames fine but for some reason it pushes `v2` name to remote. Here's the command line session:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10586]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Mahi\Documents\GitHub\EasyPlayer>git branch
  v1
* v2

C:\Users\Mahi\Documents\GitHub\EasyPlayer>git branch -m master

C:\Users\Mahi\Documents\GitHub\EasyPlayer>git branch
* master
  v1

C:\Users\Mahi\Documents\GitHub\EasyPlayer>git push origin :v2
To https://github.com/Mahi/EasyPlayer.git
 - [deleted]         v2

C:\Users\Mahi\Documents\GitHub\EasyPlayer>git push origin master
Counting objects: 39, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (19/19), done.
Writing objects: 100% (39/39), 8.17 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 39 (delta 9), reused 39 (delta 9)
To https://github.com/Mahi/EasyPlayer.git
 * [new branch]      master -> v2

C:\Users\Mahi\Documents\GitHub\EasyPlayer>
```

How do I properly rename my `v2` branch to `master`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and force the local/remote branch association with:

```
git push -u origin master:master
```

Your local config for that branch might still have v2 as its upstream branch. The above command-line should reset that.

Comment: Thank you very much! :) Extra thanks for the explanation you added, at first I had no idea why the command worked