# Renaming branch in github

Tags: git, github

I want to rename branch from 'master' to 'introduction'. I found different links,but got me confused. Any help?

I tried this,but it didn't work.

```
git branch -m old_branch new_branch         # Rename branch locally    
git push origin :old_branch                 # Delete the old branch    
git push --set-upstream origin new_branch   # Push the new branch, set local   
branch to track the new remote
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Renaming a branch in github](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524933/renaming-a-branch-in-github)

Comment: @Dario how would that help? He did exactly what the accepted answer suggests but didn't have success.

Comment: @Theo what does "didn't work" mean? Did you get some error message?

Comment: @Vampire. I got to my github and I see the master branch. it is not renamed.

Comment: But did you get any errors when issuing those commands? Maybe you have to change the default branch on GitHub for this to work properly

Comment: @Vampire. Can I change the branch name in github page? I didn't know that.

Comment: No, but you can change which branch is the default branch that is preselected when you go to the project. I think you cannot delete a branch in the remote as long as it is the default branch (like your local `HEAD`), I just thought you would get an error when trying to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `https://github.com/<user>/<project>/settings/branches` and change the default branch to being not the one you want to delete, then try again. You cannot delete the default branch in GitHub.

Comment: Cool. I can now see the introduction branch! Thanks for that. However,I believe that there should be a way to delete the master branch. I mean from the terminal(gitbash in my case).

Comment: Not as long as it is configured as the default branch in GitHub. GitHub does not allow to remove the default that is in use of course. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

1/ The correct sequence is:

```
git branch -m old_branch new_branch         # Rename branch locally    
git push --set-upstream origin new_branch   # Push the new branch, set local   
branch to track the new remote

# go to GitHub and select new_branch as your default one

git push origin :old_branch                 # Delete the old branch
```

2/ [Starting July 2020](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-07-17-links-to-deleted-branches-now-redirect-to-the-default-branch/):

> ### Links to deleted branches now redirect to the default branch

> Previously, when branches were deleted on GitHub, any links that contained the old branch name broke across StackOverflow, email, Slack and other integrations.
>
> **Links to deleted branches now redirect to the default branch.**
>
> So, for example, the link https://github.com/dependabot/dependabot-core/blob/master/README.md will now redirect to an equivalent link on the default branch: https://github.com/dependabot/dependabot-core/blob/main/README.md.
>
> This change only affects view links; other types of links (like edit links and blame links) don't redirect.
>
> This change is the first of many changes GitHub is making to support projects and maintainers that want to rename their default branch.
> To learn more about the changes we're making, see **[`github/renaming`](https://github.com/github/renaming/)**.

3/ Starting Jan. 2021

This is directly supported.

See "[Renaming a branch in GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65799427/6309)"

[image: rename branch dialog]

Comment: GitLab, of course, is not far behind: https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/07/22/gitlab-13-2-released/#configurable-default-branch-name-for-new-repositories