# Is the branch after "origin" the local branch or the remote branch?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I am trying to learn git but I am confused about one part. Usually I use:

```
git pull origin branch_A
```

to fetch the remote branch. Usually my current local branch is `branch_A` the branch on the remote repository is also `branch_A` , so I will get the `remote/branch_A -> local/branch_A`. But what if I want to get `remote/branch_B -> local/branch_A` what should I do? What is the real meaning of the branch after `origin`. It means the remote branch or the local branch? Does this command mean `fetch default remote branch to local branch_A` or `fetch remote branch_A to current local branch`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the command

```
git pull origin branch_A
```

the `origin` refers to the remote repository which you have configured in Git.  So this will pull changes from the remote `branch_A` into the local branch which is tracking this remote.  On the other hand,

```
git pull origin/branch_A
```

will pull the changes from the local version of the `origin/branch_A` branch which was cached last time you did a pull.

If you really want your local `branch_A` to track remote `branch_B` then the following command can do the trick:

```
git checkout -b branch_A origin/branch_B
```

If you *already* have a local `branch_A` tracking something else (such as remote `branch_A`) then you will have to kill the branch first and then recreate it.

Comment: if I used branch_A to track origin/branch_A. But I renamed branch_A to branch_C and created a new branch_A. And I use git pull origin branch_A. Will it be pulled to current branch_C or current branch_A?

Comment: `git pull origin branch_A` will update `branch_C`, which is still tracking the remote `branch_A`.  Your local `branch_A` won't be updated unless it is also tracking remote `branch_A`.

Comment: You probably should not be messing around with the branch names.  Please read [this SO article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526794/rename-master-branch-for-both-local-and-remote-git-repositories) for more information on correctly renaming a Git branch locally and remotely.

Comment: Thank you pretty much... One last question. Is the push the same with pull? Every time I use 'git push origin branch_A'.  Are the commits pushed from default local tracking branch to the remote branch?

Comment: Yes, `git pull` and `git push` behave symmetrically this way.

Comment: Hi I just tried. It is true that even after I renamed the 'pull' still goes to branch_C but the 'push' is still 'branch_A -> origin/branch_A' not 'branch_C -> origin/branch_A'. It seems that tracking rule of 'push' follows the name?

Comment: How did you create your `branch_A`?  Was it setup to point to the remote branch with the same name?

Comment: I checkout to the old version of branch_A and used that head to create a new branch temp. And renamed the branch_A to branch_C. Then renamed temp to branch_A........

Comment: In this case, after your changes both `temp` and `branch_C` should still be pointing to the remote `branch_A`.  Is this not the case?  By the way, you should try to avoid playing around with names.  I have been using Git for 5 years and I can't even count on 2 hands the number of times I have had the need to shuffle around branch names.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83943/discussion-between-deathlee-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Answer (score 0):

The branch after the name of the repository is a **remote** branch.

It is what the doc says [git-pull](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull).

You allways pull over the branch that you are in your local repository.

However, there is another possibility, If you have a local branch tracked with a remote branch, then the command means that you will pull in your current branch what is in the remote branch that is pointed by your local branch tracked.