# Is it possible to rename a branch in git if work has been pushed to it?

Tags: git

Is it possible to rename a remote git branch if work has been pushed to it already?

```
Master
development-branch

branch 1 
branch 2
branch 3
```

All the above branches have been pushed up to development. Can I rename development-branch to development?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rename master branch for both local and remote Git repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526794/rename-master-branch-for-both-local-and-remote-git-repositories)

Comment: Rename the local branch to `development`, then delete the old `development-branch` on the remote, and finally push `development`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
git -m development-branch development
```

more details here 
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#git-branch--m
https://multiplestates.wordpress.com/2015/02/05/rename-a-local-and-remote-branch-in-git/