# What are the consiequences of renaming the master branch in a Git repository?

Tags: git

I have an old `master` branch which is broken and should not be used.
And I have a new branch `master2` which is good and further changes should be committed to it.

Can I rename the old `master` to `master-old` and rename `master2` to become the new `master`?

Will that be an issue?

Comment: If you want to keep the history without an extra branch floating around: `git merge -s ours master` (check the syntax) into `master2`, then merge `master2` into `master`. Done!

Comment: you could just delete your old master

Comment: Obviously yes to the first question. Matter of opinion to the second. The main thing to consider is how many remotes you have.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rename master branch for both local and remote Git repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526794/rename-master-branch-for-both-local-and-remote-git-repositories)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Locally, you can rename whatever and whenever you want.
But if you intend to push, exercise caution.

Whenever you change a branch history (like here renaming/replacing one branch by another), you will have to git push --force that branch to the remote.

If you are the only one working on that repository, that is perfectly OK.
But if you are working with other collaborators who would have cloned/used the old master branch, you will need to advertise and communicate that change first.