# Git renaming 'origin/5.4' to 'origin/5.5'

Tags: git, push

Whenever I tried git push, it returns the following

```
$git push
fatal: The upstream branch of your current branch does not match
the name of your current branch. 

To push to the upstream branch
on the remote, use
git push origin HEAD:5.4
To push to the branch of the same name on the remote, use
git push origin 5.5
```

And when I checked the status:

```
$git status
On branch 0.2
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/5.4'.
```

How do I rename 5.4 to master 'origin/master'?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rename master branch for both local and remote Git repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526794/rename-master-branch-for-both-local-and-remote-git-repositories)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are using the [`simple` value for `push.default`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-pushdefault). One option is to change the `push.default` (e.g. to `upstream`), but renaming your local branch is simpler in the sense that you won't have the same thing with different names on the local and the remote side.

To rename from 5.4 to 5.5, do for example:

```
git branch -m 5.4 5.5
```

Comment: I'd suggest to rename the branch: `git branch -m 5.4 5.5`; that way the reflog history is not lost.

Comment: Oops, you're absolutely right. My "There's no renaming of branches" was just my ignorance. I'll edit to fix that.