# Looking to delete my master branch on git

Tags: git, gitlab

My current project ran into some snags and due to this I git checkout to an older commit. I did some fiddling and progress to a point much further past my master.

I then want to essentially delete the master branch or make my development branch my master.

I can't seem to merge the branch into the master as some files have been deleted or changed causing a lot of merge conflicts, I've been unable to amend these changes, trying to delete those files locally or on my gitlab online and pulling down.

I know that deleting a master is a pretty dumb thing to do, is there a way I can make the development branch my master.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I delete a Git branch locally and remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-locally-and-remotely), [Rename master branch for both local and remote Git repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526794/rename-master-branch-for-both-local-and-remote-git-repositories)

Comment: P.S. In the settings page from Gitlab, you should make master branch "unprotected` to make force pushing work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need to actually delete any branches here.  Instead, all you need to do here is to hard reset your `master` branch to `develop`:

```
# from master
git reset --hard develop
```

Then, you'll have to force push your rewritten `master` branch to the remote:

```
# again, from master
git push --force origin master
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to overwrite the remote master do
`git push origin <your_branch_name> --force`